# How many incorrect reviews will cause banning? Would it affect something after the banning duration?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, banning, review-suspension

I was told I have too many incorrect reviews and have been banned for two days:

```
You have made too many incorrect reviews. 
For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, 
see: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5752272.

Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.
```

I don't feel I made many incorrect reviews so I'm wondering about the below issue:

1. How many incorrect review will cause a ban?
2. If I make a review that is NOT a test, will that be judged to be INCORRECT?
3. How long is the ban duration? It seemed some others had three days ban.
4. When the ban duration ends, is there any other punishment that will affect me in the future?

Could someone please tell me?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> How many incorrect review will cause a ban?

[It has never been publicly stated what exactly triggers the ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214156/153008), except you can't get banned for failing one audit (this does not mean that you definitely get banned after 2, just that one failure won't trigger).

Generally, the reason the exact algorithm is not disclosed in such cases is to prevent gaming (that is, users doing just enough to avoid triggering the ban).

> If I make a review that is NOT a test, will that be rejudge to INCORRECT?

Moderators have the ability to levy a manual review ban if they feel you made an incorrect review on something that was not an audit.  The ban message will tell you that you were banned by a moderator and it should link to the review (or reviews) in question.  I can't speak for the mods on what it takes for them to issue a manual review ban, but unlike the automatic review ban, you **can** get banned for 1 bad review.  To get banned for a single bad review though, it would have to be an extremely bad review (such as approving a SPAM post).

> How long is the ban duration? It seemed some others has three days ban.
>
> When the ban duration ended, it there any other punishment will affects in the future?

Previously, the [review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562/182513) was scaled based on a 30-day window since your initial ban (2-days).  Additional failures within that 30 day window would grow to 7-days and 30-days.  Since the 30-day ban would obviously be outside of the original 30-day window, it would reset to 2-days. While this was harsh on someone who failed a few times in a short period, it was not sufficient for users who continually fail audits or get banned since it would always reset to 2 days.  So to resolve that concern, the old method was replaced in [late 2016 with new method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days) for determining ban duration.

Now, if you fail another audit in the future, your ban duration will depend on how long since your previous review ban.  If your previous review  ban (both automatic and moderator imposed bans) was within the last 30 days, your new ban will be doubled the previous one.  If your previous review ban was beyond 30 days, you new ban will be half of the previous one.

The new method is not as harsh on the front end since it grows more slowly. It can take 5 review bans (each within the last 30 days of the previous) to get more than 30-day ban where the old method was there in 3 bans.  But on the back end, it is extremely harsh, so reviewers who habitually fail audits can have extended review bans.  Do it enough, and it could eventually be years before you are allowed to review again.

See also: [Is there now a two-month review ban period?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338524/is-there-now-a-two-month-review-ban-period/338526#338526)

Comment: Well I was banned again.. And I found that after the first time banned, only one wrong review will trigger a ban again.

Comment: Which really sucks - cause I had the feeling I did at least 80 helpful and conscientious reviews in between and passed plenty tests ... too bad because quality of posts could easily be guaranteed by simply stopping the game feeling and therefore by removing the review badges ...

Comment: Considering my own experience... Before first ban (2 days) you can make 3 - 4 incorrect reviews. After first ban, you cannot make any incorrect reviews to avoid another ban. Currently I am banned for 30 days second time. But I understand it now...

Comment: That's not completly true.... I was just banned for 2 months (!) It's a bit exaggerated......

Comment: @Bidou thanks, the automatic ban info is outdated. I will fix

Comment: I get banned again and again even after passing 3-4 audits and failing only one edited Late answer. Now I am banned for 8 days.

Comment: Unfair, I passed two reviews today and failed just one. Among the dozens of helpful edits I contributed yet I was still banned. Geez... we aren't getting any points for reviewing and editing but we still pay high price.

Comment: @JamesWong doesn't matter how many you pass, just how many you fail.  And it still wasn't just one failure.  You would likely have a history of failed audits in order to trigger a review ban.  There are exceptions in the case of moderator imposed bans, but they are not typical.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Does a ban on review may cause a suspension on my Stack exchange account?

Answer (score 42):

After a lot of bans, the answer is simple:

- You can make **ONLY 3 (THREE)** incorrect reviews, the **4 (FOURTH)** will cause a BAN for **2 days**.
- After 2 days you can make **NO** incorrect reviews. First incorrect review will cause a ban for **7 days**.
- After 7 days you can make **NO** incorrect reviews. First incorrect review will cause a ban for **30 days**.

> **NOTE: the loop starts here again**

- After 30 days You can make **ONLY 3 (THREE)** incorrect reviews, the **4 (FOURTH)** will cause a BAN for **2 days**.

Important informations:

> - The type of review **DOESN'T MATTER**.
> - Passing a lot of tests, **DOESN'T ALLOW YOU** to make more incorrect reviews.
> - There is no way to reset ban.

Comment: Source?​​​​​​​​

Comment: my own experience, banned 4 times on 30-day period. I know what I write:-).

Comment: So, immediately after a 30-day ban, you can make 3 incorrect reviews again? That seems weird. Also, any clue how long it takes to reset after a 2/7-day ban?

Comment: I can confirm this. Im currently sitting out a 30d review ban. The first took 4 failed audits (I personally think 2 of those were straight bs but I digress), the second and third only took 1 each, even after passing 10 or 15 in between each ban. @Cerbrus. Bans are allowed in a 30 day window. So if you get a 2d ban on the 1.11.2015 it will reset on the 31.11.2015 regardless of what happens in between.

Comment: @Cerbrus, yes, after 30-day ban you can make 3 incorrect review again. There is no way to reset 2/7 day ban. If you get in there, the reset will be after 30 day ban.

Comment: For clarity, you're saying that audit failures in *any* queue count toward a single review ban?

Comment: Well, at any rate, I can confirm that [three](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7152887) [audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7227529) [failures](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7401265) across two queues within a 29-day rolling window did **not** cause a review ban as recently as March of this year. So either that's flat wrong, or the assertion that audit successes don't help is. Still finishing the analysis of the last queue to see if I can check the "3 in 30-day window *within a single queue*" hypothesis.

Comment: @NathanTuggy the post describes that you can fail 3, the 4th will cause the ban.

Comment: @Magisch: Huh. Don't know how I missed that. [It's](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6450271) [still](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6477478) [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6496922), [even](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6526192) [so](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6724605). (Yes, that's *two* overlapping four-in-30-days ranges across two queues.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thats directly contradictory to mine and brtlomiej's experience then.

Comment: @Magisch: I don't know what to tell you, except that I'm pretty sure that at the very least review ban eligibility *doesn't* cross queues. I have a script you can use to dig through your audits much more easily; maybe you can figure out what you've been missing that way. It's basically a modification of (an earlier version of) [rene's review peer-comparison script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/274165), autonavigating to each successive page and stopping whenever it hits a failure. I can upload it somewhere if you want.

Comment: @NathanTuggy TBH I just stopped doing reviews alltogether now. I know im not a robo-reviewer, and im not going to spend the time to dispute every single audit I find bogus on meta. And since the system insists on banning me anyways, I have come to the conclusion that SO does not want me to review things.

Comment: There is a way how you can be sure to no to be caught by audit :-)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk sure, there is any number of ways you can cheese the system. But I'm not going to volunteer my time to cheese the system and volunteer more of my time to work the system. Its on SO to design a proper system, since they want volunteers to handle the flags for them.

Comment: The only thing why I review posts is to win 8 gold badges:) that is all. I am not about to help clarify the questions or answers:)

Comment: Finally good, logical answer for ban time. There should be an option to make answer as favourite...

Comment: This is incorrect for me - I had my first 30 day ban recently, then once it expired I got **one** review wrong and the 2 day ban occurred straight away. After the 2 day ban, I only got another **one** wrong and got a 7 day ban.

Comment: @luka The same situation, just after 30-days ban have expired I got 2-day ban after **first** wrong review. Probably the review policy changed.

Comment: When you say that `You can make ONLY 3 (THREE) incorrect reviews`, you mean failing 3 consecutive audit/test reviews causes ban. Is that correct? So let's say out of 6 test/audit reviews I failed in 1st, 3rd and 6th then I'll not get banned. Failed reviews have to be contiguous to get banned as I've failed many times in last few years during review but got banned today only. Possibly I failed an audit review but passed the next one so I was escaping by chance.

Comment: This info is no longer accurate.  The review ban algorithm changed so the 2->7->30 loop no longer exists.

Comment: Is this ban loop updated ? Because I got banned for 8 days even after passing 3-4 audits and just failing one review. This is sad. They should include the ratio to number of audits passed vs number of audits failed.

Comment: i have been reviewing for a long time, got 1 time 2 days ban, then 8 days, and after i think 1 and half a month without any problems today i got a tricky question that was an audit. It was a poor quality question but the errors where tricky to see.. and i got 8 days again, this is really sad :( , the sad thing, i was 2 questions away to get my second review badge :c

Comment: Totally unfair, SO should take into consideration your edits and passing reviews as a method to allow a relative number of mistakes rather than a fixed number.