# Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

> #### Related: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

It seems I've [failed the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7445297) of user who answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033966/google-plus-one-button-backend-error-32099) correctly.

[image: Google Plus One button backend error - screenshot]

The answer was:

> I also get an exclamation mark **when I access an index directly without the complete url**, such as domain.tk/subdomain/ instead of domain.tk/subdomain.index.html. It seems that **because the url I submitted was linked to index.html**, I could not +1 when I was considered to be at /, even though I was really visiting /index.html.

This answer was far better than the other existing three answers with zero-vote (with lots of assumptions which should be more comments than the answers).

Maybe he had the problem too, but this is the reason why he's answering and sharing his knowledge (it's usually the case when people have the same problem). He stated 'because'/'it seems' and he's using specific terminology (+1) which indicates he knows what was the cause of it and he further trying to explains what was the reason. His answer is also in similar concept to the first accepted one (by comparing the terminology and the concept).

And this answer talks straight about invalid url (without the complete url) and it was confirmed in other few comments, such as:

> This led me to my fix--I was missing "http://" from my URLs. THANK YOU. –  *adamdport*

So I think what happened first person didn't read it correctly, rejected it and posted the automatic comment that it isn't the answer (aka 'If you have a different question, you can ask it here by ...' - and obviously this user didn't have another question!) and the rest followed him seeing this comment (chain reaction), so post was removed and the person who read it and understood the answer failed the audit and got banned.

Is it what happened? This is how it should work?

---

UPDATE:

Based on [Ken White comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly?noredirect=1#comment168822_288592), this is mumbo-jumpo question and it should be closed.

However this is not still clear how I should closed it or what should I do with it?

The usually options are:

> This is an "I'm having this problem, too" comment.

This was obviously not a comment 'I'm having this problem too', as it was poor quality answer.

> This is a different question posted as an answer.

This was not another question posted as an answer either.

Either it wasn't a spam or a 'thank you' kind of post.

As far as I understand, moderators should remove spam and invalid entries, but not the answers (which should be improved instead). This was the answer as it was, but still answer. Therefore if I did something wrong, then which option should I choose then to close it? None of them seems to be relevant.
So in summary I couldn't use any other option to do anything with it, either to remove it or not. As far as I know, the Edit option would trigger failure as well (secondly improvements are done in the other queues).

If this is still not clear if it's answer or not (aka 'thank you', 'another question' or 'I've this problem too'). My simple logic explanation is: the OP problem basically was: '**button turns into an exclamation mark**' and the guy is answering: '**I also get an exclamation mark ... because ... (answer part here)**'. This indicates the direct/unique answer to OP problem and it's not related to any other answers.

And as [Will said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly?noredirect=1#comment168498_288592), the audit should be obvious and questions in the form of "I had the same problem, I did XYZ, instead of ZYX, which worked." are very common and the correct answer is contained within the word jumble.

Comment: Just to refresh my comment that was on the SE version of this question: the answer was a "me too" response. Also answers should be clear and unambiguous - you shouldn't have to *interpret* an answer. IMHO it was a good example for an audit - negatively voted and deleted only answer from a new user.

Comment: @slugster You mean I shouldn't read/interpret the question at all, before closing it just for the reason how it look? For me it was quite clear that it was the answer. Most people doesn't speak English natively and this is not their fault. The question was in not good quality either. We could inform the user to improve quality of his answer, but not removing it completely after short time as some kind of spam, when other users posted much worse answer on that question and it seems they were able to stay published just by chance in this case.

Comment: Also, you don't just get banned for one failed audit, [it takes a couple failed audits to earn a ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271216/how-many-incorrect-reviews-will-cause-banning-would-it-affect-something-after-t/271233#271233), so you've missed another audit recently.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes, I know, but I'm disputing currently this one to not diverge too much.

Comment: This is borderline.  Which means the audit is invalid.  Audits should be obvious.

Comment: @Will What is borderline about it?  It's not even resembling an answer to the question.  If you can't catch an answer like this you most certainly should be failing the audit.

Comment: @Servy It seems obvious to me.  But then, I'm used to seeing answers in the form of "I had the same problem, I did XYZ, instead of ZYX, which worked."  The correct answer is contained within the word jumble.  Because of this, it is borderline--unclear, yet containing the correct answer.  Borderlines shouldn't be used for audits, period.

Comment: @Will The fact that a vegetable couldn't pass this audit doesn't make it borderline.  It's a very clear case with a very clear correct answer that every reviewer should have a 100% success rate with.  It's a fine audit.  If someone's choosing the incorrect action because they didn't actually read the post clearly then *the audit is doing its job* and causing the reviewer to slow down and read more closely.

Comment: I think it's obviously an answer (I could tell that only by scanning it and finding the words such as 'because'/'it seems'/'it was working fine') and marking it as another question with the comment: 'If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question.' was not appropriate way of handling it.

Comment: That's a terrible answer, and just because you can piece together a word here and there to find out it might contain a solution doesn't make it acceptable. If the poster wanted to actually provide an answer, the whole "I had this too mumbo jumbo more stuff fixed mguoig by ramble ramble" should have been stated as "This is caused by X, and the solution is Y" instead. No one cares that you had the problem too, and you shouldn't have to carefully filter out the noise to find the words that are relevant to the solution.

Comment: @KenWhite The answer was mumbo jumbo the same as the question was, so important thing is that they're on the same page (maybe it was useful for OP, not for moderator). So next time I should remove that kind of answers if they're not clear (without giving user chance to improve, or OP to see it and comment on it)? So that means it's safer to remove stuff just in cause it could be an audit? I don't feel it's right thing to do only to be on safe side (I feel bad that we're removing things which could be useful for others to solve their problems), but if those are rules, then I'll follow them.

Comment: @kenorb: If the question was mumbo jumbo, it should have been closed. A poor answer is a poor answer, whether it's to a good question or not. (I would have found the question again and downvoted/close voted it after dealing with the poor answer, so they were both appropriately handled.)

Comment: Also, FWIW: the linked answer has been deleted, with a comment that it should have been a comment instead, and the poster of the answer replied *True, I should have added a comment, not an answer. Sorry about that. *. (Visible to 10K+ users by clicking the link to the question in your post.)

Comment: @KenWhite I know it was removed, that's was this was the main trigger of audit to show (which was the result of choosing the wrong option by other moderator). So you're saying I should close this answer. How I should close/improve this answer then? I didn't have any appropriate option for that. I've updated my question to show you my point.

Comment: Definitely not obvious. It's not a 100% unambiguous "I have same problem plz send solution to xyz@yahoo.com" type answer.

Comment: @kenorb The fact that you failed the audit because you didn't actually read the post, and instead acted purely based on a few keywords that you saw means that *this audit was doing its job*.  You choose the incorrect action for an answer because you didn't read it closely enough.  The answer was only saying that another answer to the question worked for him; it wasn't actually providing an answer itself.  Clearly this audit was *extremely successful* in its task of finding reviewers who aren't reading the posts in sufficient detail.

Comment: @Servy I actually read the post, including the question, as I was checking for any mistakes in this post (especially '+1' thing, then I knew it was referring to Google Plus), but after that it was making sense. I've always editing and improving the answers if the post is rubbish (no punctuation, no proper sentences or some typos) - check my history if you wish. This was a proper post in my opinion, it had proper sentences with periods, new line at the end and no typos either (I've seen worser answers). Of course I could add a bit formatting, and rearrange the answer,but it's not the main point

Comment: @Servy The person who actually didn't read the post, was the first who chosen the wrong option for it and adding non-related comment, as it wasn't the question. And the rest who followed him, by seeing the comment. So actually I'm guessing I was the only one who read the question in this case.

Comment: @kenorb How does the grammar/formatting/spelling of the post have anything to do with whether it's an answer or not?

Comment: @kenorb The post is 100% not an answer.  You should have flagged it as NAA from the first posts queue.  You didn't; you approved it despite the fact that it is not at all an answer.  That was *wrong*, and you failed the audit as a result.  As for the comment, it's an autogenerated comment, and it is in fact the correct choice of action that the user's selected from the queue.  The autogenerated comment for that action needs to be fairly generalized, to make sense in response to a large variety of comments.  It doesn't make as much sense here, but that's the problem with autogenerated comments.

Comment: @Servy If the answer has missing punctuation, new lines, no formatting and contain lot of typos, it's worse and it's not readable (so then you won't tell the difference if it's question or answer). This also indicates the author doesn't know how to write a proper answers, then it should be closed. This one I didn't have to re-edit, other than rearranging or bolding the answer part.

Comment: @kenorb Those are all possible problems with an answer, yes.  None of them have anything whatsoever to do with whether or not the post is an answer, or is Not An Answer.  Note that answers are never closed; the very idea of closure don't apply to answers at all.  You should have flagged this answer as NAA.  You didn't, and as a result of your failure to flag a post that should have been flagged, you failed the audit.  One of your most important tasks from the queue is to find and flag posts that merit further moderation action, such as posts that aren't answers.  You failed in that core goal.

Comment: @Servy I don't remember if I had 'Not An Answer' option present, but I'll check next time. Then I should treat poor answers as non-answers then. Is there any reference/link/rule/documentation for it? Or it's non-written rule aka how it is done currently.

Comment: @kenorb THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER.  It is not answering the question.  It is stating that another answer solved his problem.  THAT IS NOT AN ANSWER.  That you mistakenly thought it was an answer because of a few keywords, out of context, made you think it was an answer, doesn't make it an answer.

Comment: @Servy 'It is stating that another answer solved his problem.'. He's not stating that another answer solved his problem. None of the answers were similar to his. OP problem: 'button turns into an exclamation mark' -> guy answering: 'I also get an exclamation mark ... because ... (answer part here)'. This is the direct/unique answer to OP problem, it's not related to any other answers.

Comment: (building on what @KenWhite said) that it is a terrible answer means that "no action needed" shouldn't have been selected.  The post should have been commented on, edited, flagged, or down voted. Any of those would have passed the audit.  The failure of the audit isn't the debatably ambigious "it is not an answer" (which the OP of the answer admits), but rather that "no action needed" was selected. Action *was* needed and not taken... and the audit was failed.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks, but from last time I've learned that editing poor answers cause immediate audit failure as well (as you can't edit something that was already removed). So Edit won't work in this case. However the down-vote method is a good idea in this case, but I don't know if I had access to them. In some queues you don't have.

Comment: @kenorb so do it outside of the review queue then (which would have shown the audit nature).  Or skip it. But "no action needed" means nothing needs to be done, the post is suitable in its current form... which it isn't.

Comment: @MichaelT Sometimes if the post is suspicious (not obvious candidate to closure), I'm opening it in new tab to see if this was removed already (which indicates audit, as removed posts are not shown in queues) to double check if I'm making the right decision (as other moderators making often mistakes as well, as in this case) and follow that decision. But in this case the answer was an obvious answer (no question/no spam/no links), so after reading it (inc. question) and making sense I haven't close it, as there was not even appropriate option to do that.

Comment: @kenorb with first posts and late answers, you will often find people posting answers that are entirely material within a previous post posted years ago - just restated. This other answer doesn't show up in the first post review queue (you get summary information). This is part of the check one should do for *every* first post review to make sure the answer isn't a duplicate of another answer (which may/should be deleted). This is even the case with what would consider an obvious answer. Furthermore, if the post is poorly written (as this was), a comment about how to improve it is in order.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a first post review.  You clicked "no action needed" or attempted to upvote.  Either way, that fails the audit.

Why is this an issue? Because first post reviews are one of the first sources of feedback to the OP about the quality of the answer and possibly working on helping the OP to improve the answer.

- You could have down voted "no, this answer is not useful". That would have passed the audit.
- You could have looked at the question to see if there was another answer that the answer duplicated (which would have immediately shown the audit nature) (seriously, there is all to often people post another answer that is entirely contained within a pre-existing answer - especially the case when the question was posted two and a half years ago - some of the other answers might have this material already)
- You could have up voted the comment about it not really answering the question (in which case it would have shown the audit nature)
- You could have attempted to post a comment about how to improve the answer (linking to the help center how to answer) (this would have shown the audit nature)
- You could have attempted to post a comment refuting the existing comment about it not being an answer (this would have shown the audit nature)
- You could have asked for clarification about how the answer answers the question. (this would have shown the audit nature)
- You could have up voted the comment from the OP of the answer "True, I should have added a comment, not an answer. Sorry about that." and flagged it for a moderator to convert to a comment on the appropriate post (which would have shown the audit nature).

Any of these things would have caused you to pass the audit.

You are *expected* to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there (and doesn't reinforce good ones when *they* are present with an up vote).  You have 20 reviews per day for this queue - it's not a race to get through them. Spending less than 10 seconds per review is not the focus of this review queue.

If you do not feel that you are qualified to help the OP on a particular question (and this answer did need help - help that you did not provide... and remember that there is only one pass through a first post audit), [there is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/289086).

As this is the first post review queue, I will also make mention of my post on Programmers.SE answering the question [Looking for guidance on using “No Action Needed” in the first posts review queue](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6681/40980).  Another take on how to review in these queues can be found in [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/289086)

Much of the discussion in comments and attempted refutation in the question is based on the 'not an answer' aspect.  **This is irrelevant**.  The issue is that 'no action needed' was selected for a post that needed action. That it was an answer or not is not at issue.  The issue is that action was needed on the post. Selecting 'no action needed' on such a post prevents the OP from getting necessary feedback about the quality of the post itself because first post review queue is a one pass only - one review completes it.

When a post needs help, clicking 'no action needed' is the wrong action.  This post needed help in some way, shape, or form - be it guidance in a comment, a vote, a flag, or editing (and yes, that is a chancy thing to do). The OP of the post admitted that it needed help (it was a comment, not an answer). Someone reviewing it should attempt to fix these things rather than click 'no action needed'. Clicking no action needed on this, as a review audit failed the audit because action was needed.  How clear exactly *what* action needed to be taken isn't at issue - *something* needed to be done and *nothing* was. Review audit failed.

Comment: Note that comments are not shown on FP or LA audits until after the audit is revealed, unlike other queues, so several of these possibilities wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Accordint to your answer... I try to comment post `https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24424244` just to mention to remove the NOTE and UPDATE and I mention in my comment that I will upvote it. And as soon as I add my comment, I receive `You didn´t pass` the audit. Why that one is happening?