# Review Audit Failure: Answer is not an answer?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I got a no-pass on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7566575

If you look at the comments, this is clearly the answer, but it was then flagged as a non-answer? It should probably be edited because it was clearly copied and pasted from the comments, but how is this not the answer?

Comment: What did the audit ask you?  It's a downvoted, deleted answer, flagged as VLQ.  Why would you mark it "No action needed?"

Comment: ["At 20 reviews a day limit, one has plenty time to do more thorough check of reviewed posts before clicking Looks OK..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251155/165773)

Comment: But it IS the answer. Maybe the question as a whole is problematic? Maybe the OP should have posted it as the answer? Regardless of the quality, it is the answer. Does a correct answer that is low quality deserve to be deleted? I'm not the one that didn't review it properly IMO. The person who deleted it didn't since deleting this does not seem to be the correct course of action.

Comment: Looks like the OP merely copied the comment to a self-posted answer, including its signature and date posted.  Not really the best form; I can see why it was downvoted and flagged.

Comment: @Necreaux I think a answer with low quality should also be deleted. As personally I used SO to find the answer of my problems but each when see any low quality post, I skipped such answers. And again try to find a good or better answer which can provide me a solution with reason of issue.

Comment: I can totally see why it was downvoted and flagged, I'm just questioning whether that was at the end of the day the best course of action. What confuses is me is what is the correct course of action for that answer? If the goal is to have that question answered, that goal was clearly met. Is that question being improved by having that answer deleted?

Comment: My answer is: "Meh."

Comment: @Necreaux The goal of first-post queue is to help new users learn how to use SO and write good posts.  In this case, the answer literally copied a comment.  Without any additional information (like explanation or other sources), this "answer" provided no additional content.  Explaining this in a comment and downvoting are appropriate actions.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I agree, I think it could have gone either way depending on who saw it, a close call.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks! That helps, although that isn't the same as flagging and deleting it. I have no idea if I would have still failed the audit if I had done that.

Comment: @Necreaux I believe that any action that isn't "No Action Needed" or upvoting counts as a pass (for "bad post") in first-post audits.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for that. It looks like some mods are more aggressive about reversing these. Although I think my question is not a duplicate because it refers to a separate instance. I saw another question somewhere saying that disputed-review-audits is the place to post in this situation.

Comment: you may find an [explanation here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601) useful to avoid failing such audits in the future: "You are _expected_ to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there..."

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not this answers the question...I'd say that this is probably a wonderful edge case in that we have a poorly written question which earned a poorly written (by other standards) answer.

The answer *is* appropriate for the question, but the real issue lies with the question.  There's not enough detail or information to suggest that reinstalling Java is the right thing to do at first blush.  One has to go out to another site (read:  Google) to determine that this is what the particular error code means to do.

Not a fan of the audit review; I think you got caught in a poor loop.  Personally I'd have skipped this one, then went back to close the question and downvote the answer.

In either event, the answer also has to be objective.  How can one be sure that this is **the** right thing to do if the question itself is very much open to interpretation?