# How did 3 reviewers miss this blatant plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, new-users

There's something wrong with the *Review Queue for First Time Posters*. See here where a straight up rip-off from another answer was posted, **reviewed at least three times**, and no one noticed the blatant plagiarism.

[image: Copied answer screenshot]

The copy-answer duplicates the first paragraph of the only other answer so far on the question. Indeed, if it weren't for the comments from the reviewers, on the main site the copied text would be seen 3-in-a-row, with no intervening objects except for signatures and white space.

How could so many people miss this? Trying to clear the queue too quickly? The review interface interface hiding adjacent answers? ..?

(Plagiarism is not really the right word. This wasn't somebody seeking to pass off someone else's work as their own. Looks more like a bot writer figuring out how to beat the system to me.)

The post in context:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30523442/14420

Comment: The other answers aren't shown in the review queue. That's probably related.

Comment: @ProgramFOX, so maybe something like is what is used in the Low Quality Posts queue is needed then, with the Q&A shown underneath in muted colours. http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/

Comment: Same in that queue: the question is shown, the other answers are not.

Comment: The review queue isn't the right place to handle plagiarism anyways. Raise a custom flag instead.

Comment: @ProgramFOX, thus the "something like" preface phrase.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: The FP/LA review queues are *the* places to deal with it, by raising a flag and commenting. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @Deduplicator But reviewers don't see the rest of the answers, how could you expect them to catch this? Expected behavior is not to open up each post you review to check for stuff like this. So no, the review queues are *not* expected to catch/deal with plagiarism, at least in their current form.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET the point is this could have been easily caught at the first review point (if more context was shown). Relying on the custom flag means more work, because a) the post goes through the 1st queue, people spend time on it, then b) someone else raises a "hey this is a copy!" flag, and finally c) more people review the custom flag. It's inefficient.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, it's not good that for doing all the checking you have to do, you actually need to look at the profile, other answers and also do a quick search or two. Part of that could be integrated into the UI (and imho should), but part cannot. Anyone not wanting to do that, should not review in those queues at all. Or at least click "skip" instead of "looks ok" if he does not find anything fast enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator Until/unless the other answers are shown in the queue, I don't see plagiarism detection as being a function of the review queues. If it *is* shown, then sure, its a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @mattwilkie Note that the custom flag would be handled by a mod, not a review queue

Comment: Anyway, this was the FP review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8245614 and this was the VLQ review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8245816

Comment: Why would it be reviewed three times?

Comment: There's something wrong with the Review Queue for First Time Posters. See here where a straight up rip-off from another answer was posted, reviewed at least three times, and no one noticed the blatant plagiarism. ;)

Comment: @VividD: _There's something wrong with the Review Queue._ Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 51):

Just to be clear, First Posts / Late Answers reviews only require *one* reviewer. In this case, the reviewer in First Posts flagged the answer as "not an answer", which dropped it into [the Low Quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8245816) where it was *very* nearly deleted... Before one reviewer made a very stupid edit.

I've gently encouraged this editor to pay more attention to his reviews in the future.

Comment: It seems strange that a single edit be able to cancel five deletes?

Comment: Yes, [5 of the neccessary 6](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8245816) "recommend deletion"s are certainly narrow. @TZHX: They were not delete votes, of which 3 would have sufficed. And if you edit, you publicly take some resposibility for the post, so you get more say.

Comment: I don't get it. The 5 "recommend deletion" votes are 9, 7, 6 and 5 hours ago while the single Edit action was only 2 hours ago. (Though maybe my low rep level means there's activity not shown to me?) http://i.imgur.com/85YCYcm.png

Comment: @TZHX "single edit" may for example turn 200% delete worthy link-only answer into a solid quality content (I did such edits myself and saw others making this "magic"). That's why it makes sense for system to drop the post from review. What makes _much less sense_ though is that system indiscriminately treats any edit like a guaranteed salvage and doesn't even let mods take a look, see eg [Edits shouldn't dismiss “not an answer” flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252854/edits-shouldnt-dismiss-not-an-answer-flags)

Comment: @gnat Or it may not, which is why it could also make sense not to treat an edit as a 100% trustworthy "there is absolutely nothing wrong with this post now, pinkie swear".

Comment: @TZHX yes that's exactly my issue with current treatment of edits. I am okay with dropping edited posts off the queue, but it doesn't feel right that this totally discards all prior flags. Presumably the idea is that editing [meta-tag:bump]s the posts for more eyeballs to take care of re-flagging if needed but I doubt that this works

Comment: @gnat ok, I wasn't entirely sure what your PoV was. Sorry.

Comment: @gnat's right, the way that edits immediately kick things out of review has caused a lot of problems. I've personally had to go back and delete many non-answers or even spam posts that were immediately removed from review because of misguided edits. For example, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6384598 that had four "not an answer" flags all invalidated because of that edit in review. It lasted on the site for two months before someone noticed and re-flagged it.

Comment: @BradLarson why I am not surprised. Expecting single edit bump of a relatively old question to bring enough attention to catch wrong edit sounds like remainder from pre-historic times when SO was getting, like, 100-200 active questions a day in popular tags

Answer (score 23):

As the other anwers state, the reviewer does not see the other answers. Since we talk about nearly identical copies, why couldn't the system catch it on its own and put such answers into a new plagiarism-queue for humans to check (with context)?

Comment: don't expect your answer to be noticed or commented on, since it is intelligent and correct.

Comment: You disproved yourself by commenting on my answer... ;-)

Answer (score 18):

> The review interface interface hiding adjacent answers?

Actually yes that's it.  In order to see the other answers, you have to open the link to the question.  The question is provided, but no answers appear.  Only the number of other answers appear, and I personally don't really think to check if the post is plagiarism.

Also, plagiarism requires an "other" flag that moderators have to process.  Because of this, I feel that this is not the intended use for FP/LA queues.

Aside from the plagiarism, the answer (as seen in the picture you provided) is also a *bad answer* that doesn't explain anything.  The plagiarism attempt didn't even include the solution.  This should have been handled properly regardless of the plagiarism.

Comment: I emphatically disagree with your final sentence: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts

Comment: Ok, so we have the answer to "how did this happen?". Now I'm more interested in the rest of the question (raised if not explicitly asked): "Can this be made better?"  I don't think anyone should be wasting their time posting "this is how to give a better answer" comments and tweaking formatting when a showing the reviewers a little more context might reveal the correct response is "flag for delete and move on".

Comment: @mattwilkie there might be a [meta-tag:feature-request] for this.  If not you can create one.

Comment: It isn't a bad answer, seeing as it is not actually an answer at all.

Comment: "Selecting 'no action needed' on such a post prevents the OP from getting necessary feedback about the quality of the post itself because first post review queue is a one pass only - one review completes it..." ([Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601))