# How does preventing me from reviewing for 7 days help me become a better reviewer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, review-suspension

I just received a 7 day ban for selecting "No Action Required" on an answer that seemed fine to me.  The answer was specific to the question and gave a resource to help.

But regardless of the value of the answer, what am I meant to do with these 7 days that will help me become a better reviewer? How should I figure out what to do next time?

This was the audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8565822

Comment: What would you propose doing instead?  Having said that, the answer in question is very clearly not okay, and unquestionably requires action.  You absolutely did do something "naughty".

Comment: See [A day in the penalty box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) please.

Comment: I thought it was just to prevent you from screwing up more.  Perhaps goad you into learning why what you did was incorrect?  Maybe make you more conscious once your ban is lifted?  Saying "no action required" on spammy answers that should have been comments if not flagged as canned meats is a big red flag on your reviewing skills.

Comment: _How does banning me for 7 days help me become a better reviewer?_ They are assuming you'll stop doing the thing that led to the ban. In this case, marking link only answers as "No Action Required".

Comment: It was NOT a "spammy" answer.  But since I clearly don't understand, please HELP me understand.  Why was this a bad answer?

Comment: I am trying to LEARN, not be chastised for not understanding.

Comment: And why are you guys down voting me for trying to learn?  I am not complaining, I'm trying to get better.

Comment: @Lance You're not being told that the answer is spam.  You're being told that it is not an answer, it is merely a link to an answer.  The comment on that answer even explains this, and links to a relevant meta post on the subject.  Note that you didn't ask us to tell you why this is a bad answer, you proposed not banning people that fail audits.  if you had asked us what the proper course of action is for that audit, then people would answer it.  You instead claimed that you did noting wrong (which isn't asking to learn, it's claiming you don't have anything to learn).

Comment: @Servy I am sorry I didn't phrase the question in a manner you approved of or understood.  But I was looking for a learning opportunity here, regardless of how you wish to parse it.

Comment: @Lance And I'm telling you that if you wanted to learn what you did wrong when reviewing that post then you should *ask what you did wrong when reviewing the post* instead of stating you did nothing wrong and proposing a change to the whole system.  if you want to propose a feature that's fine, go right ahead, but just don't expect people to be psychic and answer questions you aren't asking.

Comment: _"Note: My question is completely different from the proposed duplicate."_ If that's the case, don't just say that but _explain how your question is different._ Otherwise, your question is _still_ going to get closed because the close reviewers see nothing telling them why the question is not actually a duplicate.

Comment: Please re-read your question, without any preconception of what you *want* it to mean. Place extra emphasis on the title.

Comment: _I am trying to LEARN, not be chastised for not understanding_ First of all, I'm not the one shouting. Secondly, the only thing I did was answer your question. You responded by accusing me of saying something I didn't and then getting angry that I didn't answer a question you didn't ask (even though I did).

Comment: @BSMP My comment wasn't directed to you.  It was meant for the comment immediately above your where it was called a spammy answer.  And I'm not shouting.  lol

Comment: And I have to say, I am completely shocked and saddened by the way you all treat someone asking a question and looking for help.  You guys really need to reevaluate the way you treat people because in this case, it really sucked.

Comment: Your attitude was sucky to begin with.  Your question is ranty, you aren't willing to accept that your decision was incorrect, nor does it seem you're willing to learn.  Seems like the 7 day ban was appropriate.

Comment: Your comments on the answer are much less so than the ones here... odd.

Comment: Look, I asked a question because I didn't understand what I was being punished for.  I had incorrectly assumed this was the place to do it.  Instead, I find more grief for no good reason.  You may keep it.  But, thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: "You are expected to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there (and doesn't reinforce good ones when they are present with an up vote). You have 20 reviews per day for this queue - it's not a race to get through them..." ([Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601))

Comment: @gnat It was not a First Post review.  It was a Late Answer review.

Comment: @Lance ["Review late answers from _new_ users"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) -> "You are _expected_ to take some time to help guide a new user..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... how does
>   banning me for 7 days help me become a better reviewer?

It forces reviewers to re-evaluate their reviews.  After all, it prompted you to write this meta question.  In my experience, reviewers typically go through this re-evaluation immediately after their *first* failed audit.  This helps them learn what the current SO standards are and make better decisions in their reviews.  Many times, they will post a meta question for failed audits to better get a grasp of what the community feels is appropriate.  The review ban is a last-ditch effort to help reviewers align their reviews with what the community feels is appropriate.

> But regardless, the value of the answer is debatable ...

It's really not.  This is a clear case of a very low quality (not-quite) link-only answer.  That is, reading only the text (without an active link) yields this answer:

> To simplify things here's a jQuery plugin that does that without the hassle: `https://github.com/haggen/readonly`

This doesn't even contain a readily-understood name for said plugin.  That text is useless as an answer and should (IMO) be deleted as Not-An-Answer.  Regardless of the minutiae of NAA, it definitely lacks and explanation or other redeeming qualities as an answer.  In the context of the First Post queue, informing the new user by commenting on the post and/or downvoting are also acceptable actions.  <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> is definitely the wrong choice.

For more information, read this [Guide to Reviewing in the First Post Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts).  It's long, but fairly helpful.

Comment: Okay, @ryanyuyu now that makes sense to me.  Thank you for taking the time to understand.  For what it is worth, this was me second failed audit.  The first one was clear to me and I have tried to pay much closer attention since then.  This one escaped me though, which is why I came here to ask.  Thank you.

Comment: @Lance no problem.  Yeah the meta of moderation is fairly deep.  There are a lot of [meta-tag:faq] and [meta-tag:faq-proposed] questions dealing with these sorts of things.  Above all else, don't be afraid to research or ask questions here.

Comment: I don't know...  Considering some of the comments above, I doubt I'll ever ask another question here again.  I am not used to getting chastised for asking for help.

Comment: @Lance It's all about phrasing things in as neutral of a tone as possible while also showing what research you've done.  With a bit more practice, you'll find that the users who frequent meta are very helpful.  I think that most of the pushback was from a perceived lack of research, since this kind of post was among the first kind of post reviewers learned about.

Comment: It still seems to me that a 7 day ban is more of a punishment than a teaching tool, but I guess I get it now.  The way I judged it was simple: had that been my question, I'd have appreciated that answer.  Clearly that isn't enough though.

Comment: @Lance Unfortunately, you can't judge the quality of an answer based on how you'd appreciate it if you asked the question- We have specific standards here. The 7 day ban may seem like a punishment, but if you _use it_ to take time to learn more about the site, then it actually becomes a teaching tool. It's telling you something's up with your reviewing habits and you should take a look at what that is. Next time you go to ask about a failed audit, ask _only_ about the audit. Explain why you took the action you did and ask why that was wrong, and you'll get a better response.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: For even more reading, the canonical post about link-only answers is on Meta.SE: [Your answer is in another castle -- when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) @Lance

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, I understand that.  It just didn't seem to me (at the time) like it applied for this particular answer since it wasn't a link to an answer.  It was a link to github repository for a specific library designed explicitly for the purpose the question was about.  Can you explain to me what would have made the answer acceptable?

Comment: Generally one wants to see some sample code that demonstrates how the linked tool applies to the exact situation in the question, @Lance, or at the very least some prose explanation (as the comment that Nathan Tuggy left below the answer suggested -- his link goes into the rationale). Otherwise the answer is not much better than a entry in the search results I'd get from Google.

Comment: @Lance there is a difference between acceptable as a "valid answer" and a "good answer for a new user".  Since the point of the First post queue is to educate new users on how to better use the site, any answer that is a plug-in recommendation requires attention (at the very least some helpful comment).  Even if the question asks for a recommendation.  Answers should be complete.

Comment: @Lance  If you need more guidance, do more research or ask a new question.  You'll get better information (from more than just 2 people) that way.

Comment: Okay @ryanyuyu But just FYI, it wasn't the First Post queue.  It was the Late Answer queue.