# So I failed this review audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9325395

There is no doubt that this is a crappy answer, but it is an attempt to answer the question. He is stating "maybe you can't parse your URL because it has extra text in it".

We are told to have high standards when choosing to flag stuff. There is a flag reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

As bad / wrong as this answer may be, it's not flaggable. It's not even necessarily downvotable. This answer should not be an audit.

Can I have my review ban reversed please? (Note: I don't contest my other failed audits, I wasn't paying attention then, but I *was* being more careful this time).

No @gnat, not every failed audit question is a duplicate of every other failed audit question.

Comment: So wait.  If you knew the answer was bad, why'd you say "No action needed"?  Also, why would you *flag* when all you'd really need to do is downvote this question?

Comment: @Makoto I didn't think it was bad enough to downvote.

Comment: Why would you flag it, then?

Comment: @Makoto I didn't flag it, I chose no action needed.

Comment: Sorry. *Maybe you have a problem because...* is not an answer. It's a comment suggesting something to (possibly) examine. Action is needed, and you chose not to take any.

Comment: No I agree, the audit mechanism sucks I failed an audit when I said no action needed, on a post answer that actually gave a valid answer to contribute, someone else improperly down voted them, this audit mechanism should be more robust and only put ones where the actual answer is more definite on what to do

Comment: "There is no doubt that this is a crappy answer..." => _that_ makes it totally a duplicate, see [the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601) over there for a detailed explanation what's wrong with clicking No Action Needed in cases like that. In brief, you deprived a new user (LA queue is for answers posted by _new users_), you deprived them the opportunity to learn how to use the system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The First Post and Late Answer review queues are a bit odd in that there's no single appropriate action; you're expected to evaluate a post and take *any and all* necessary actions, which could range from flagging to upvoting.

Oh... And there's that "no action needed" button. Which exists because when it didn't folks were just upvoting everything, even when it was horrible. It's a tacit admission that many reviewers don't really know what to do for most posts entering those queues.

Which isn't to say that it is ever an appropriate response, particularly when faced with an answer that your peers have found confusing and unnecessary. You're quite right: flagging that answer isn't necessary, nor should you downvote it if you don't feel comfortable evaluating the technical merits - but you can at least see that the answer is problematic and do *something* to address this: edit, or leave a comment at least.

Comment: My point was not that I did the *best possible action*, it was that this post was not so bad that it should be an audit.

Comment: My point is that if you know what you're doing, you should *never* chose "no action needed". Hence the audit as an educational opportunity.

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that NAN is literally never, under any circumstances, the correct review action? Or did I miss some implied context?

Comment: NAN is *by definition* **not an action**, @Nathan. You're saying that the post you're looking at is perfectly neutral, neither good nor bad, unable to be improved or moderated. This is... Extremely unlikely; a more plausible explanation is that you do not personally know what to do with the post but are unwilling to click "Skip" for some reason.

Comment: I just thought of something; how many people does it take to clear a First Post or Late Answer review?

Comment: One, @durron597

Comment: Perhaps it should be more, especially if No Action Needed is almost always wrong? [Good discussion on this issue](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6681/88986). Maybe I'll make a separate meta question about it if I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, we tried that briefly. Bit of a train-wreck. See also: [why I hate these queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234153/how-can-we-make-first-posts-review-actually-useful)

Comment: @Shog9 Weird, I didn't get pinged with that last comment of yours. Anyway [I made the meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266027/200235)

Answer (score -2):

I'll let you in on a little secret: *if you're not sure, go to the actual question*. Have a look, you get a bit more context than what you do on the review screen.

If you'd done this, then you would have seen that answer was deleted five days ago. That's a big indicator that this is an audit review. Am I giving away valuable information here that is going to destroy the review system? Nope, I'm not. If you discover that it's an audit by visiting the question then *Congratulations!*, you're taking that little bit of extra effort that is going to make you into a super duper reviewer. I have visited the question many times while reviewing, and I often find an absolute mess where multiple answers need editing or flagging, or the question itself needs to be closed.

So if that answer hadn't been deleted, then you have to do something. Some answers are just plain crappy, and the simplest thing to do is just hit the *Delete* button. If you can't because you feel bad for the author and you can kind of see what they were trying to say, then use that insight and jump in and edit it instead.

If after all that you're still not really sure, then hit the *Skip* button.

Comment: I wasn't unsure, I legitimately thought nothing needed to be done.

Comment: @durron597 Then you've legitimately failed the audit. Sometimes the audit sample isn't the best, this wasn't the most obvious audit. But then my first advice prevails: visit the question, get some more context.