# Was this a bad audit in the First Posts queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

[I was hit with this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9387242):

[image]

I failed it as the answer was removed as 'NAA' (Not An Answer).
I disagree with this as it obviously *is* an answer (it may not be a good one, but it is what it is).

However I can also see why it might be considered NAA:

- Too little information- *what OTL examples?*
- No explanation on what `#define` is and why it is needed
- No `code` formatting (although this shouldn't mean it's NAA)

Perhaps downvotes + requests/edits to make the answer better (*I remember that editing answers to add more detail or update them is fine as long as it doesn't affect the answer*), but certainly not NAA.
I might also add that as a result of the answer being deleted, the question no longer has any answers.

I can see this being a borderline case, but, was this a bad audit?

As [S.L. Barth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/812149/s-l-barth) [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304247/was-this-a-bad-audit?noredirect=1#comment241847_304247), a bad answer is *still* an answer: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Using the guidelines [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) I would say it is an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was a [unanimous deletion in LQPQ](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9199103)

Comment: @NathanOliver Agreed, I don't mind much about the failed audit as the majority of audits I'm hit with, I pass.

Comment: I agree that it was an answer; it attempted to answer the question.

Comment: A bad answer is still an answer. As per the [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) meta post.

Comment: What action did you take?  This is a bad answer in the First post queue.

Comment: Maybe the auditors simply misinterpreted 'should include [...]' as 'should include [...] in your question, so we can answer it' (which, if intended, should have been a comment) rather than the actually intended 'should `#incude` [...] in your program to fix the problem'?

Comment: @das-g YES! I read it that way at first as well. It **is** an answer, but it's very easy to misinterpret as a request that information be added to the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Yes**, it was a bad audit, it [is an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), even though extremely lean.

But "No Action Needed" is still the **wrong** decision:

Unless there is really

1. no clarification neccessary,
2. no guidance to offer to the author,
3. the post should not be flagged and
4. it is really so bland at the end that it is perfectly neutral,

[when you think of clicking "No Action Needed", you should "Skip" instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303739) after doing as much of the list as you can and are willing to do, to give someone more competent (and patient) the **chance to do it right**.

And as the outcome of it's previous sojourn in the FP-queue and its fate in the VLQ-queue ([unanimous condemnation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9199103)) makes obvious, you should have edited it (if you didn't recognize it as an audit), or brought it to a moderator / 20K-users attention for corrective action if you did.

See: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

---

I edited it and [then it was undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32067118/revisions), so it is certainly no longer an audit.

Comment: I agree with everything except "it was a bad audit".  Mainly because as you point out, "No action needed" is the wrong decision.  So if that's definitely the wrong decision (I agree that it is), the audit is legitimate and accurate.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: It's a "known-bad"-audit, but the answer isn't actually that bad, which is the yard-stick I used for evaluating it. Imho, it's too subtle (*anything* but editing (or skip, naturally) would have been wrong, and the audit-system cannot handle that) to make a good audit.

Comment: Well the current behavior for commenting in the FP/LA queues is "comment" --> post is bad right?  So even something as minimal as leaving a comment would pass the audit right?  I get what you're saying that this audit is subtle though.

Comment: Unless the comment behavior has changed, [clicking add comment ends the review audit in FP/LA](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment).  Another duplicate of referenced post [Why did i failed this First Post Audit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286434/why-did-i-failed-this-first-post-audit?rq=1)

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Well, FP and LA audits are generally suboptimal, because there are too many perfectly useful thing one can do there. About the only thing which should always give a specific result for the audit-system is blatant spam.

Comment: Yeah, that's really true.  Well I guess I don't have any complaints about the audit being discarded since it was a bit subtle.  I guess that answer just immediately set off my personal alarm bells.

Comment: [This is a good reference to back up this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303739/1768232)

Comment: In general: No Action Needed is always the wrong decision.

Comment: If 'no action needed' is always the wrong decision why is it provided? And what exactly about the answer needs improving? And why should a receiver be expected to edit? This is getting quite out of hand.

Comment: @EJP: See the link I incorporated from durron for Shog9's words on that.

Comment: There was not any 'Recommend Editing' or any similar button for the audit.

Comment: @Deduplicator Triage? This was the First Posts queue.

Comment: @cybermonkey: I didn't say you had (or could) recommend any of the above action, only *do* them.