# Yet another bad audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

[In a review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9403107) I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950633/1505120) to [How can I allow flex-items to grow while keeping the same size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074473/how-can-i-allow-flex-items-to-grow-while-keeping-the-same-size) which was deleted by [a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson). The accepted answer included *This is something that cannot be expressed via CSS Flexbox right now.*
The deleted answer links to [Managing CSS flex-box growth in multi-line to create a grid of equal blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621449/managing-css-flex-box-growth-in-multi-line-to-create-a-grid-of-equal-blocks) which has no accepted answer but one that includes “This is totally possible, however …” and another includes “you have explicitly declared that you don't care for the boxes to be equally sized”.

The deleted “answer” appears to be a fair attempt at being helpful so, to me, seemingly useful. As it happens, I particularly appreciate answers that dare here to say "Not possible" - they can avoid my spending more time in failed attempts and fruitless searches than many other answers save me.

The deleted answer does not include spam or unattributed content and does not offend me. None of the bullet points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) seem to apply to it.

**Why was it deleted or why should it have been/remain deleted and is it appropriate for use as an audit (which I failed)?**

---

[image: Banner]

I’m wasting my breath again but answers to *Is it what happened? This is how it should work?* (about [Google Plus One button backend error -32099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033966/google-plus-one-button-backend-error-32099)) which, for example, has nothing to do with ‘link-only’, does not address *Why was it deleted* where ‘it’ is an answer (now Comment) to [How can I allow flex-items to grow while keeping the same size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074473/how-can-i-allow-flex-items-to-grow-while-keeping-the-same-size).

Maybe [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly) does **indirectly** provide an answer to my question, but given I have had and have accepted an answer to my question I am not prepared to trawl through *all* the answers to *a chain of other questions* – for the same reason, but with considerably more justification, as users have been objecting to a link to *one* specific answer, to one specific question.

Comment: Remove the link and ask yourself: How does *"It’s not perfect, but this is the only solution I’ve seen that achieves the desired effect using Flexbox"* answer the question *"How can I allow flex-items to grow while keeping the same size?"* ?

Answer (score 12):

> It’s not perfect, but this is the only solution I’ve seen that achieves the desired effect using Flexbox:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616083/1922441

That's a [link-only-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) (redirecting to another SO answer), and thus should be flagged NAA and deleted.

As the comment says:

> If the question you link is an exact duplicate, then this question should be closed as a duplicate. Otherwise, you should provide a complete answer to this question instead of a link-only answer. –  josilber Aug 11 at 20:16

Comment: @pnuts: It doesn't say anywhere that link-only answers pointing to a SE site (even the same one) are exempt from the rules. Still, put the not-so-important qualification into parentheses.

Comment: @pnuts: Answers should be answers, not redirects. Read the castle-post.

Comment: Can links to other SO pages break? Yes, they can, though not to (the newest type of) dupe-targets. Anyway, we already have a feature for marking duplicates, and it is not "post an answer". Though there's a FR somewhere dealing with incentives for duplicate-finding which proposes showing potential duplicates as votable answers.

Comment: The answer does not stand on its own. It's a link only answer that doesn't tell anyone anything about the solution. The answer should include the relevant solution in the answer itself, not just link to it. *No Action Needed* was the totally wrong action. If you did *Edit* to add the relevant solution with proper citation to the answer, then you'd definitely have a valid claim for an incorrectly failed audit. The audit  was a good audit in this case.

Comment: ["Is there even one tiny speck of information there? No. Even the title of the page being linked to would have provided something to go on, but that was entirely too much work.

So let me be clear: this sort of response is not an answer. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, delete it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) ~ [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)

Comment: @pnuts no where on that question is the word *external*.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114448/should-an-answer-linking-to-another-answer-be-converted-to-a-comment , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-just-links-to-other-stack-overflow-answers, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow, this has been discussed before multiple times, the consensus that I'm aware of is they are at best a comment, should be edited into a real answer, the question closed as duplicate, simply deleted, or a combination of those actions

Answer (score 8):

I'm the moderator who acted on that answer, and you'll notice something about the delete action:

[image: Deleted answer]

I didn't completely delete the answer, I converted it to a comment (which [you can see below the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074473/how-can-i-allow-flex-items-to-grow-while-keeping-the-same-size/31950633#comment51813705_28074473)).

I'll be the first to admit that I'm not a huge fan of the policy towards deleting helpful answers that consist of a link towards another resource. However, it's really easy to deal with answers that contain no additional information but link to post on Stack Overflow: convert them to a comment. That preserves the link to that other question (in case someone wants to refer to it or vote to close the question) while cleaning up answers to focus on original contributions.

No information was lost here, merely converted to a more appropriate form. If the answer had added anything more to the problem (a potential solution in addition to the link), I would have declined the "not an answer" flag and left it alone.

If you see an answer like this in review that links to another Stack Overflow post without any additional information, your best bet is to flag it and let moderators review it.