# Yet another questionable review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Here's another question about review audits...

I got this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11911485

[image: example screenshot, questionable audit]

Although this was "identified as possible spam", the way I see it the user was actually trying to answer the question, so I reviewed it as "No Action Needed". Is the answer good or bad? I don't know, but for me that is an answer.

I asked the good chaps from the SOCVR chat and they agree, so I was advised to bring this to meta. I got the info this post was flagged as VLQ, but the funny comments are actually giving the idea this is NAA.

Is this a bad audit or should I see things from a different perspective?

PS: I got one of those pesky bans, because sometimes I suck at reviewing. Hey! At least I'm trying!

**EDIT**

This question was marked as duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly), but in this case I don't know if the answer is correct or not (I don't even think that's relevant). However, that question leads to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), and that, I agree, is a good resource. Cheers.

Comment: The SOCVR chat room agreed with you? I'm quite surprised. That late answer looks like it should be a comment to me.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the user wasn't trying to answer the question?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Wait, now we try to be nice and we still get burned ...   ;)

Comment: @rene, I wasn't aware the purpose of that chat room was being nice ;)

Comment: @Cthulhu, maybe they *were* trying, but the user's intent is not relevant here. Only the end result counts.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not sure I understand your point. The way I see it, the end result is an answer. Maybe it's not a good one, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: TBH I don't think that needed deletion. It is an answer, and I've `Looks OK` far worse in the LQP queue.

Comment: I guess the main point is that an audit should be *clearly identifiable* as either crap or a gem. Since a bunch of us disagree (I was one of the people suggesting this meta post) about the kind of crappiness of the post in question, it should not be an audit. (cc @FrédéricHamidi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that is an attempt to answer the question and not just a comment. It shouldn't have been delete voted from the VLQ.

The answer provides a slightly different take above the other answers that only state that what the OP wants can't be done. In that sense this answers tries to provide a solution for something that is deemed impossible. But I'm not a Java dev, others will probably correct me.

You could have prevented choosing the wrong reason. As the review system put up a nice banner for you:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

which for me always is an invite to visit the question and answer outside of the queue (click the link on the right) to inspect the context of the post. That would have revealed if the posts was deleted or not and with that choose the right option. After that you can still come to meta to discuss the audit if you found the audit counter intuitive.