# Failed low quality post audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13179384

Looks to me like it provides some good information that may well be the cause of the asker's problem. Having had this problem myself, it seems like the files not included in the zip are no longer available on the plugin server (although it doesn't specifically note this to be fair).

I noticed that the answer has been deleted, so it could be why it was created as a review answer? Or am I just off base on this one?

EDIT: the "answer":

> Development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is no longer provided by Andorid development team. They developed the "Android Studio" for improving the development experience. More details are available on the following site: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

(not a duplicate of [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592) - it just happens that the answer was also deleted)

Comment: Ahh I thought that everyone would be able to see it. I'll add it to my question!

Comment: I see. I often skip questionable questions/answers like this one (looks like it provides useful information, but on the other hands, mostly it's a link only, should I pass/reject it?). :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: Just to note: I would have skipped this one regardless of what the answer looks like - I don't review answers when the question itself is absolutely no good (*"Why to install ADT needs a long time?"* - yeah, take your pick of any number of reasons, most of which have nothing to do with Eclipse or the plugin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this might be valuable information for the author or anybody else viewing the question, *it does not answer the question at hand.* ADT doesn't fail to install because the development team ceased development on it. It might be that the OP needs to download the plugin from a different source, but the answer doesn't tell that.

This answer was posted by a real user; all audits (except those for Suggested Edits) are taken from real Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: Then I wonder what delete reason would be given? It certainly does attempt to answer it (admittedly not thoroughly), and is very on-topic and helpful. Do you think it should have been a comment instead? These all fall under the same reason, just trying to grasp why it was removed in the first place.

Comment: It's hard for me to evaluate the answer since it has been deleted, but as I understand it, if it *does* answer *some* question and contains valuable information, it probably shouldn't have been deleted, even if it doesn't answer *the* question. Downvoted maybe, but not deleted.

Comment: @rjdown, yes, posted as a comment it would definitely make sense. We don't have delete reasons - it is likely that one of the [reviewers (FP or LA)](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38399218/timeline) used a VLQ flag on the post.

Comment: @NisseEngström the answer is now quoted in this question. It doesn't matter that it answers *some* question. "Chris Froome" is also the answer to *some* question.