# Bad review audit: Workaround for a problem with Zeppelin 0.7.3

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I do not think [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19197381) should be an audit.

The top comment, that it should have been a comment may be right, but lets look at the answer:

- The answer contains a workaround, including the concrete version with the problem and the version without the problem.
- The answer contains details to the whole stack involved, making debugging easier

It did not really solve the problem, but it is a solution to "I need to get it working again. Now.". So while it is not the best answer it should not be an audit as it is unclear why it should not be helpful to somebody.

In the comments is the explanation why it is no comment: The user did not have the needed reputation, yet. And he explains that the solution helped him after searching several hours for any solution:

> @user2807083 It offers a solution to the problem. I spent several
>   hours looking for any solution. I agree that, perhaps, it should have
>   been a comment, but as I said, I don't have enough reputation for
>   that. – rouckas Mar 10 at 17:41

I do not think I should have got the review ban for my "no action needed" click (no upvote).

Having a closer look at the [other not deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49000746/893159), the solution there is the same: "You need another version". While it links a corresponding github issue, it stays unclear about the versions needed to get it working again or if it will work at all:

> Somehow you still encounter the problem. *I think* either downgrade Spark or use a newer version of Zeppelin *could solve* the problem.

while the other post contained exact version numbers of a working stack.

Comment: Not having enough reputation to comment does not make it okay to post a comment as an answer.

Comment: You didn't get a review ban for failing **this** audit. You got a review ban for failing **all the other ones you failed previously**.

Comment: If this audit would not be an audit, I would not have the ban.

Comment: I removed comments which are now included in the question.

Comment: From the [FP/LP guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), I think this bit is particularly pertinent: _Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough, especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new:-> Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does; if so: -> Downvote; comment if practical._

Comment: Personally, I would think that course of action would have been better than clicking on _"No Action Needed"_.

Comment: And again, the comments saying "I can't comment yet" are more a red flag than a reason to be lenient with the answer.

Comment: You do not see the comment in the review queue, I saw it when looking at it afterwards. @yivi maybe this would be better. But I think using it as review audit is a bit harsh, given that it probably (I did not test it) contains an actionable answer. For a developer it is no good answer, but for someone wanting to deploy the software it is what he needs at this moment: a) Yes, the version is the problem b) With these versions it will work.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sympathetic to the answer (though it ignores the advice in the other answer which strives to *identify the problem*).

I'm less sympathetic to your review.

If you see what you believe is a reasonable answer *beset upon by criticisms*, then certainly *some* action is needed! Edit the answer, provide some advice to the author on how to make it more explanatory, *something...*

Remember: these are people who are new to writing here. They haven't necessarily absorbed much if any of the cultural norms that we take for granted. **They need your help!** If you see a post that's going to do poorly and hit "No action needed"... You're leaving them to bleed to death by the side of the road. Have mercy...

Comment: this looks like somewhat bland repetition of points that were much better presented and explained in a [canonical duplicate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601)

Comment: These points are worth repeating. The "canonical" itself it's a duplicate... And besides that, this answer talks (if only a little) about the _specific_ post that triggered this audit, which the OP is at pains to defend as a _good enough_ answer to justify clicking _No Action Needed_.

Comment: @gnat I presume this is Shog voice growing weary that such easy and simple course of action is being ignored again and again, to which I'm always sympathetic.

Comment: I see the point, but I do not see why this answer is actually DELETED. It was an improvement (even when no high quality one) and provided a solution. In the triage queue I would have voted "requires editing", but for the first post queue this is no option so you either need to discourage the well meant answer, skip it or fail the audit. Okay, editing would have helped, but I would not have had much to add.

Comment: @allo wonder if you are aware that [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @allo Maybe it didn't deserve to be deleted. But it certainly didn't merit a "no action needed". In that sense, it was a perfectly sensible audit.

Comment: The "canonical" answer suffers from the canonical problem with these, @gnat: it focuses on the myriad ways one could avoid failing a known-bad audit. In this case, the author believes the answer is reasonable, and recognized that others felt differently... So why didn't they do anything to facilitate better communication? To rescue the answer? I think we can stand to make this point a few more times.

Comment: @allo If you don't think you'd have anything to add in an edit, then why would you mark it as "requires editing" in triage?  How are you expecting other SO users to edit the post into shape?

Comment: @Servy I would expect the person who wrote the answer to revise it. Just because of your argument: For others it is work they need to be motivated to do (i.e. because they exactly know what to add), but from the poster it can be expected to improve his answer when it's unclear / badly written or has very bad formatting.

Comment: @allo, then you clearly misunderstand the meaning of _"require editing"_ in the review queues. When you click on that, you mean that the post would benefit of **someone else than the author of the post** editing it. If it _needs editing_ by the author, it usually means the post should be closed.

Comment: Okay, then I will edit more myself next time or skip it. I thought it triggers the "please edit or it may be closed" flag. When do you get noticed when someone clicks it? Is it a queue you get access to at a higher level?