# Review audit fail: Is a short answer always a bad answer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers, specific-audit

I think that there are some questions in which the best possible answer is a concise one.

So when I came to this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24886034), after hesitating a bit (I often skip these *traps*), I decided to accept it because:

1. The question seemed to *call* for a short answer
2. This answer provided a command apparently suitable for the issue presented in the question (it wasn't up to me deciding if the answer was *technically* valid)

... but it was *a trap*.

**Why I think this failure has to be disputed?** Because the actual reason why this answer was marked as a low quality one is that the guy who answered wrote a short answer copying some others well upvoted answers.

But how could I know it? Shouldn't the reviewer only judge the answer itself? The audit didn't provide all the information to mark that answer as a low quality one, and for this reason it should be removed from the audit list.

**I strongly believe that any test (let's think for example to University exams) should be *standalone*. An exam that can be passed only looking at the solution is not a true exam, and that's the case. An audit that can be passed only detecting it is an audit.**

This ban is really painful, because it comes after a very long list of consecutive passed audits (I don't know how many: 20?), but since it isn't my first ban they seem to not give me any credit from the banning system perspective. And since ban periods double each time it's going to be an unfair punishment for what I judge a *dishonest* audit.

Comment: I NEVER ignore comments. But comments may be hidden in audits (and it was in this case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: @gnat thanks for your effort, but I think that it is a different scenario.

Comment: [answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601) seems to address exactly your case, "You could have looked at the question to see if there was another answer that the answer duplicated..."

Comment: Ok, but that's a different question, even if these questions have the same answers. ;D

Comment: The audit system is clearly broken. I fully agree with you, that an audit should be solvable standalone. The claim in the answer below, that you prove to pay attention by _looking_ for audits demonstrates this quite strongly. Also, the heuristics for audits dig out so many unusable examples. Having said that, I would not like to be responsible for building a sane review system with audit checks, this is probably not possible without huge manual effort.

Comment: @Ctx You are not supposed to be "looking for audits". You are supposed to be "reviewing the posts". In the case of late answer and first posts queues, many times that **requires visiting the question**. Anyone who expects to review on these queues and never visits the question to make a decision, is not paying enough attention, and this review audit is checking for that behaviour, as I've already explained this in the answer.

Comment: @yivi I disagree, the review system is supposed to present all relevant information to the reviewer. Everything else is broken and inefficient. Just my opinion...

Comment: @yivi *Anyone who expects to review on these queues and never visit the question to make a decision*... But how can you determine that i NEVER visit questions with a single audit? I acutally  **often** visit the question to make my decision. I generally skip a good 80% of proposed reviews (sometimes even after visiting the question!), I manage a 10% of blatantly spam/link only/not answers and I visit questions for most of the remaining reviews. Was I wrong this time? Probably. But I just would not believe anyone stating to visit EVERY question, and visiting EVERY link to detect plagiarisms.

Comment: @Cubo78 Why do you see the ban as "painful"? Is it so much fun to do reviews? I see it as a duty helping the system run, if "the system" (reasonable or not) decides, that you do more harm than you help, just leave it be and spend your time with better activities ;)

Comment: I never said **you** never visited the question when reviewing. But you should have visited the question on this case, which you didn't and got caught for it. No biggie. On LA and FP you need to visit the question **often**. Anyone who's not up to that, can just leave the queues for other users. Again, this is all explained in the guide I linked to.

Comment: Bans are not from single errors. They are from multiple errors. Problem review posts are not causing you bans. Bad reviewing is causing you bans.

Comment: @yivi it is probably worth noting that visiting the question is needed when reviewer is going to give a positive review. For vast majority of negative reviews this isn't needed ([discussed in more details at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314697/165773)). Heck, when I see late answer saying something like "Have this been solved?" I don't need to look anywhere else at all to vote down and flag NAA

Comment: @gnat You are right. It's kinda obvious in hindsight, but the distinction had escaped me nonetheless. That one is a very useful hint for reviewers.

Answer (score 12):

No, short answers are not "always a bad answer". But you were reviewing in the "Late Answers" queue, and there the bar is not simply "this is an answer", but you would need to check more thoroughly if the answer is actually good and useful.

If you read the [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) for reviewing on the Late Answers and First posts queues, you will find this bit that I think applies to this situation:

> In either queue, if you see an answer that:
>
> [...]
>
> - Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough, especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new:
>
>   - Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does; if so:
>
>     - Downvote; comment if practical.

The answer you reviewed just repeated the same information that two older answers had already provided. As such, just clicking "looks OK" is not the correct course of action. Vote, comment; or at least skip so other reviewers can review they post if they chose.

But kicking the answer out of review is simply not helpful.

Regarding this:

> An exam that can be passed only looking at the solution is not a true exam, and that's the case. An audit that can be passed only detecting it is an audit.

It seems like you have a simplistic view of audits.

Yes, if you visited the question, you would have discovered that the answer is an audit.

But that's not "looking at the solution", but *exhibiting the behaviour the audit is testing for*. Namely, "paying attention". If you do not visit the question, in cases like this, **you are not paying enough attention and your review is not helpful**.

Keep in mind that, as gnat pointed out in comments above, visiting the question is almost always required when and only when the review result would be positive (Looks OK / No Action Needed). With bad/unsalvageable posts is rarely, if ever, necessary.

Comment: I understand but you have not convinced me at 100%. First of all is a really subtle topic. Then is something that would of course reaveal that a review is an audit, and it doesn't make much sense. And finally, a _punishment system_ in which bans are unrelated to the seriousness of the mistake (added to this terrible period-doubling system) has a really bitter taste. PS: I didn't downvote you

Comment: _First of all is a really subtle topic_. Yes, you need to be vigilant to subtle stuff when reviewing. And "something that would reveal that a review is an audit" is something that you need to do to properly review posts. So it's all good.

Comment: @Cubo _"Punishment system"_. This is not a punishment, per-se. You are blocked from doing work-for-free, because the work-for-free you were doing was subpar. It's an opportunity to better learn how to work-for-free in a more helpful manner. It's a long suspension because it happened many times to you in the recent past. That means you haven't learned form past mistakes. Use this opportunity to do so, and there will be no more review suspensions in the future.

Comment: @Cubo _"I understand but you have not convinced me at 100%."_ Frankly, It's not about _convincing_ you. It's about trying to explain you how it works and how to do it better in the future. You are "not convinced", but it's you the one that keeps failing audits. I'm just trying to help you do it less from now on.

Comment: @CertainPerformance no. They were hidden in the review page (in audits answers may be altered). I often open the actual question page, both for revealing audits and to better understand what answers are related to. But this time it looked really fine (and I reviewed from my phone). I've skipped soooo many similar reviews... bitter taste.

Comment: I know audits hide scores and deleted status, but I thought comments remained, hrm...

Comment: So, @yivi, don't you think that an audit that can be passed only discovering that it is an audit is faulty? Again, I understand the ratio, but this audit is faulty. And again, it is not clear why tens of passed audits should not provide you some tolerance for future fails. Ok, nevermind.

Comment: @Cubo Respecting a ton of stop-light give you zero leverage to fight a _"didn't stop at a red light"_ ticket. This is similar.

Comment: @Cubo And the audit is not faulty, it's just that you weren't reviewing it properly. In the case of late-anwers, many times you **should** be visiting the question. If you are not doing that, you are not reviewing properly. The audit is very good at teaching that and encouraging good reviewing behaviour, and thus not faulty at all. If you haven't, I encourage you reading the guide I linked to. It's really helpful to become a better reviewer.

Comment: @Cubo78 You're right, comments do get removed from audits *before* you click on one of the buttons, at least in some circumstances. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24887179

Comment: No, @yivi . Ok: I wasn't reviewing properly. I'm ok with that. Let's go beyond it. I'm just sayng that an exam that can be passed only looking at the solution is not a true exam. ;) I'll edit my question with this metaphor and I'll go to finish my work ;)

Comment: @Cubo78 Your metaphor is slightly wrong. It should start with "An exam that can be passed only by looking at the context ...". As yivi wrote, you're in the "late answers" queue and you need to check the context of that post, like how old it is, if and what answers already exist etc.

Comment: @Cubo78 I would just re-emphasize what others have said: In the "Late Answers" and "First Posts" queues it is actually *very important* to click the "link" and compare the answer with others given (if there are any). It is actually really common for new users to post answers that are near-copies of others - I'm not sure that this is with any malicious or nefarious intent - probably just that they have yet to fully learn about the site and its methods. So, this audit is actually a very good one for the Late Answers queue, as it tests the ability to deal with a common problem.

Comment: @yivi "become a better reviewer"... This is really a problematic development, when an automated heuristic system tries to condition humans for a specific behaviour. Sounds not like something desirable. In this specific case, I consider the review appropriate. If we conducted an unbiased double-blind vote for this, I think, the result will not be unambiguous. SE would be well advised to improve the systems, which rely on the free donation of time of the users, otherwise more people will completely cease reviewing and the queues will grow (as it is already the case).

Comment: "*an exam that can be passed only looking at the solution is not a true exam*" but that's also not the case here. Here is the proper behaviour - you should have visited the question. Even if that wasn't audit - if what you saw was *really* the answer you saw with no comment, then the steps you should have taken to determine whether the post was OK or not are *the same*: 1. Visit the question 2. Check the context. This being an audit changes nothing sans saving you a tiny bit of time after visiting a question. So, the exam is if you *behave* properly, not if you know the answer by heart.

Comment: _"an automated heuristic system tries to condition humans for a specific behaviour"_. This is silly. The "automated heuristic" was actually designed and built by humans, trying to elicit said behaviour in other users. You make it sound like it's "us vs them, skynet is coming, run for the hills". Also, neither FP nor LA have a problem of "overflowing queues", so it's preferable to have less but better reviewers, than more reviewers, but less accurate. @Ctx.

Comment: @yivi In the fiction, skynet was also designed and built by other humans. The problem is, that the design is erroneous and might do harm. This is indeed often the case, is this new to you?

Comment: The heuristic is good, IMO. Users reviewing this kind of question without visiting the question is bad, and saying it isn't is weird. I'm out of here. Thanks for you input. Peace. (Maybe you want to post your own answer defending a different point of view).

Comment: @yivi These are all statements without any foundation. But I understand that you are not interested in a discussion about that and I respect that. I just hope that other people are more interested in actually improving systems instead of only defending their deficiencies and claiming "everything is good". This would be the demise of this platform. Thank you, too. Peace ;)

Answer (score 5):

It was a difficult audit, perhaps, but it did highlight something very clearly: your review was wrong.

That answer was flagged for deletion for a valid reason and required deletion. Not because of its substance but because of its circumstance.

It really is that simple. You chose the wrong action, and you thus failed your audit.

Review often has consequence for posts, so it is important that if you are going to review content, you at least review with the same type of rigor you afford when creating content.

Comment: I can easily defend my opinion, that another (albeit redundant) answer does not do any harm, hence it is not as simple as you try to make it look like. It is ok, that the answer was deleted by some people for a valid reason. But in my eyes, it is not ok for the review/audit system to define this as the one and only valid action, which it "simply" isn't. Declaring differing opinions as _invalid_ is the problem here.

Comment: @Ctx - The answer was borderline plagiarism, and deletion was the correct course of action. If you would like to defend an opinion, please start by posting it as an answer. Comments are meant for clarifications, not extended discussion.

Answer (score 2):

As it happens I wrote [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58929138/#comment104123539_58929138)<sup>*</sup> on the answer

> This is what two other answers say.

that was hidden from you during your review.

I encountered the answer in [this LQP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24620582)<sup>*</sup> on November 19th, added the comment, and voted to delete the answer.

When the answer was in the LQP (Low Quality Posts) review queue, it was voted for deletion with a 4:2 ratio: not unanimous, but enough to get the answer deleted. Note that when the LQP review happened, two users also failed to notice the duplication and went with "Looks OK" - one of them after I posted the comment (which would have been visible at that time). It being deleted by multiple users in review [doesn't necessarily mean](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007) that it should have been, but in this case, it definitely should.

For that reason, it is a valid review audit. Following the link in reviews is not only the best way to spot audits, it is also recommended, as [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) points out in [the other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392277/1364007) - *especially* if the review says that there are multiple other answers to the question.

---

<sup>*</sup> The links won't show deleted posts for non-[10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) but you'll have to take my word for it.

Comment: Another negative aspect in this whole issue is, that the user obviously created a new account to post an answer, which got deleted subsequently a bit later. The user, probably very demotivated, did not perform any more actions and the account is probably dead by now. Why is it so bad to have a redundant answer (which was not obviously plagiarized) at the bottom of the answer stack to this question? Is it worth to expel new users with such unkind behavior? I for myself would prefer to get new users to know a bit better before performing such actions.

Comment: @Ctx I share your concern about demotivating new users! However, this issue is best approached (IMHO) by leaving a *polite* and helpful comment on the post before voting to close. But your comment is a bit off-topic in regards to how the review queue audits should work: in this case, I maintain my opinion that this particular audit is a *very good one* for the LA queue.