# Wait, what's actually wrong with this question? (Review audit question)

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25115710

I just failed this audit question for choosing 'Looks OK'.

The question seems good:

1. The user has some code
2. They say what they want
3. They say what they output is.

Ok, maybe the issue is in this

```
the input/output result is as follows.

input 3 / output
input 3 1 / output 6 6
input 2 2 / output 6 6 4 Success: process exited with code 0.
I think the testCase input also affects the a input. What's the problem?
```

Where they're not clear on what actually the problem is.

Now -for one - I'm not familiar with the technology that this user is asking about.

But to my quick scan of the question, it looks like a pretty well formed question - and it's a bit of 'Wait, what do you mean by that last sentence?'. It's a more salvagable question than anything.

ie. the user clearly has some kind of problem, otherwise they wouldn't be asking. This question likely should be salvaged by saying what their expected output is.

Is there a meta question that deals with the question I'm having more broadly?

Comment: Did the view you saw include  the comment (currently at a score of +3) saying, *"This code does not produce this output."*? How did that factor into your review, if at all?

Comment: @CodyGray Good question. Not at all. It's possible that this is a typo like question - in which case - the close flag reason should be different?

Comment: @CodyGray That [tripped me up too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392276/review-audit-fail-is-a-short-answer-always-a-bad-answer/392277#comment745537_392277) when looking at a similar situation - audits *do* sometimes remove comments

Comment: "*I'm not familiar with the technology that this user is asking about*" -- never forget your friend the **skip** button.

Answer (score 11):

> Now -for one - I'm not familiar with the technology that this user is asking about.

It is not safe to vote to reopen on technology where one does not have a reasonable level of competency.

While many times it's easy to vote to close for reasons of *form*, which can can be judged by anyone, there are closures that depend on knowledge on the technology involved.

> But to my quick scan of the question, it looks like a pretty well formed question

Voting to reopen, particularly if one is not knowledgeable of the technology the asker is using, requires more than a "quick scan". One needs do verify that one really understands what is being asked and that one can imagine possible and useful answers, reading the comments to the question to try to gather more information, etc.

Remember than the presence or absence of comments is secondary. That a comment exist (like the one that was posted under that question, and which might not have been shown to you during review) does not mean that a comment is actually right, and that a comment does not exist does not mean that the *question* is fine.

> i.e. the user clearly has some kind of problem, otherwise they wouldn't be asking.

That's not a reopen reason. Nobody doubts that the user "has some kind of problem". The closure is not meant to signal that they user didn't need help, but that the question is not fit to be answered and/or kept around.

> This question likely should be salvaged by saying what their expected output is.

Yes. And that something only the asker can do. If they do that, maybe the question could be reopened.

> *(From a comment on your question)* It's possible that this is a typo like question - in which case - the close flag reason should be different?

That's not a reason to reopen a question. It is better to close a unsuitable question for the wrong reason that not close it at all. Reopening it just to close it again it's a waste of time for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The user here obviously has some problem with his environment.

He is correct, that his first input `3` is also read in a second time for the first `a` value. This would *exactly* yield the results he observes.

Now he **should be questioned**, **how** exactly he **enters the input**, to determine the source of the duplication of the first number.

Some possibilities:

- Input entered in some IDE
- Input from a file redirected to stdin
- An online code IDE
- A certain terminal

Just *closing the question without specifying, what is needed/missing*, was in my eyes the wrong way. It is disputable, if voting to reopen is applicable or not. On one hand, I for myself would indeed need clarifying details to answer the question. On the other hand, someone else might immediately know what the error is with this program behaviour. I think, both options (leaving closed or voting to reopen) can be reasoned for. As such, in my opinion, this is a bad audit question and should be removed.

The comment below the question is a bit stubborn and not helpful; I for myself believe the OP, that he observes the output he shows from the given input.