# Why did I fail this review audit of a vague attempt at an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension, late-answers

I was suspended from reviewing queues after the 5th incorrect handled review. But I am trying to understand the reasons why the [concerned post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28242840) was considered bad and needed to be reviewed.

I chose "no action needed" only because I have flagged similar answers before as either 'not an answer' or 'very low quality', but peers declined my flags with the reason 'flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer'.

Therefore I feel confused and insecure in reviewing 'late answers', since the criteria of whether an answer needs review seem too subjective. Could anybody give a hint on what would be an appropriate review for that case?

---

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the comments and the downvotes, I will be sharing my declined flags here, so you can point in what these answers are different from the concerned case I raised here, which I decided not to flag.

[image: Declined flags]

[How to get Oracle SQL query to sort by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358261/how-to-get-oracle-sql-query-to-sort-by-column-name/66019320#66019320)

[I Can't reference an image in next-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546370/i-cant-reference-an-image-in-next-js/65793150#65793150)

[Node.js error in Vaadin Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248583/node-js-error-in-vaadin-spring-boot-application/65720100#65720100)

**NEW UPDATE ON CUSTOM FLAG TO MODERATOR**

In my first reviews I often flagged custom flag, but I realized they must be used too specifically, that's why I avoid using them. Again, these tricky answers can lead to incorrect reviews or flags.

[image: Declined moderator flags]

[Convert NV12 to BGR by NVIDIA Performance Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121668/convert-nv12-to-bgr-by-nvidia-performance-primitives/65699795#65699795)

[fake path error in Jquery ajax file upload in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680190/fake-path-error-in-jquery-ajax-file-upload-in-asp-net/65603878#65603878)

[Find avg ctc of a particular bu_ssu on basis of month using hire date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489565/find-avg-ctc-of-a-particular-bu-ssu-on-basis-of-month-using-hire-date)

Comment: The purpose of the LA review queue is more than categorize posts in “answers” and “not answers”. Read [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/1426539) to better understand what’s expected from reviewers in that queue. Flagging was not your only option.

Comment: Downvoting, flagging, editing or commenting would have passed the audit.

Comment: That answer was deleted and converted to a comment by a moderator.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, after suspension I looked at the actual question and found that. But how could I 'guess' that? IHMO, I think SO should review the criteria for review audit.

Comment: If you read the guide I linked, and try use _that_ criteria when going through the review, you'll be caught flat footed much less often. You wouldn't have been caught by this one.

Comment: If you thought that it was a low-quality answer (which appears to be the case), then you should _not_ choose "no action needed". There are other actions that _should_ be used as others have stated. When in doubt, **skip, skip, skip**.

Comment: The answer was deleted but you said the answer needed no action to improve it, you would have known this if you had opened the question in another tab, which is something I suggest all reviewers do for every review.  You honestly thought an answer that contained "I think that the sorting functions could help." but didn't provide any specifics on how to use the sort functions didn't need to be improved by the author?

Comment: @SecurityHound I have come across similar answers which I flagged, but the flag was declined! That's my complaint, the subjectivity of the person who judges this. Many answers like this I've flagged NNA and VLQ and was denied, and when I flag NAN, I was caught in a trap! Anyway thanks for this advice "you would have known this if you had opened the question in another tab, which is something I suggest all reviewers do for every review."!

Comment: @yivi thanks for the link provided, I really appreciate. I've done this "Downvoting, flagging, editing or commenting" several times, but I think the audit should not be so biased of an opinion of one or a group of people, because I am not supposed to know when a review is an audit, and that's the purpose of auditing. The problem is, if I do downvote, flag, edit or comment an answer that seems to me wrong but the other reviewer thinks it is not, it becomes a subjective matter of opinion, purely.

Comment: Regarding the answers you flagged in your edit: they all recommend a _specific_ solution, which this one doesn't.  The MS SQL solution on an Oracle question is debatable, because that answers *a* question, but not *that* question...but the other two clearly recommend specific solutions.  Wrong answers are still answers.

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares - Are you downvoting these answers that you believe require moderator attention?  If you had done that, you wouldn't have failed the audit, two of your examples are the accepted answer to the question.  The third has already been deleted I believe

Comment: "Wrong answers are still answers" That's what I understood afterwards. Anyway, everybody is subject to what other people will think and judge, there's no escape. If someone thinks my opinion is wrong, that's another opinion, but if everyone thinks I am wrong, that's no longer an opinion, but a consensus, a clear sign that I must change my concepts. I just think that should be clearer, BUT, I'm just another guy giving another thought..

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares on meta downvotes don't have the same meaning as SO. Here downvotes represent disagreement. You don't need to close your question as needing details or clarity. It is a good thing that you are trying to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: @Yatin, if that's the case, I humbly think the description should be changed "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpCfE.png

Comment: Are you familiar with [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. In fact, it's a useful question, and it reflects some genuine points of confusion. There's no reason whatsoever for it to be closed. It certainly isn't unclear. Furthermore, we never close questions because they've received downvotes. I've rolled back the edit and reopened the question. I don't even think this is an exact duplicate. Certainly, many prior discussions are *relevant*, but this is a case that deserves its own answer, Ryan's provided an excellent one. The more general problem is quite intractable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like an answer at first blush, but it's actually pretty much content-free.

Imagine that you asked how to build a bookshelf, and I said "I think that a hammer and some nails could help.  You can find some hammers and examples of how to use them by going to Home Depot and asking someone there for advice."

While technically I've sort of pointed you in the right general direction, I have definitely *not* told you how to build a bookshelf.

This answer does that: it suggests some supplies for your bookshelf, but so vaguely that it would apply equally well to building a shed or a deck.  It doesn't answer the question.

For answers like this where the fact that it's not immediately obvious why it's not an answer (NAA), I'd send a custom flag for moderator attention explaining why it's NAA.  A recent flag of mine (which was marked helpful) along these lines was (with minor edits):

> NAA, should be deleted (custom flagging because it may not be immediately obvious from the answer text itself). "use merge layout inside include and then access it" is just what the question is asking how to do, thus making the only thing this adds the link...so it's link-only.

As discussed below, note that "not immediately obvious" includes anything that would require looking at the question for context, as moderators review "Not an answer" flags quickly and with little access to context. They're best reserved for obvious cases, with custom flags for anything requiring an explanation.

Comment: You will also need some wood.

Comment: Again, in similar answers, I've flagged either as "not an answer" or "very low quality", but the reviewer declined with "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer". What I have learned from this is "always open the actual question in an anonymous tab before answering", because I don't want my flags to be declined and don't want to be suspended from reviewing again

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares for cases like this where the reason it's not an answer isn't obvious at first, a custom moderator flag can be helpful.  Moderators review "Not an answer" flags quickly and with little access to context, so they're best reserved for obvious cases.  I added an example to my answer of how I flagged a similarly subtle NAA recently. As far as the very low quality flag goes, it's...almost never the correct flag on answers.  It probably shouldn't exist.

Comment: Note that "not immediately obvious" includes anything that would require looking at the question for context.

Comment: Pointing someone in the right direction is often better than nothing. For example, telling someone why their attempt at a solution fails is useful even if it doesn't provide a corrected solution -- and in many cases it's all they actually need.