# Review privileges suspension on short answers

Tags: support, review-suspension

I have being reviewing late answers these days. Two of them were short answers but correct, I reviewed them as OK but they were flagged by other people as low quality so I have been suspended for further reviews because of this difference of criteria.

The suspension message says that maybe I was not actually reviewing the tasks, but it is not the case and, as I was suspended before (and more justifiably), the penalty is a long time. Is there a way to reduce that time as I was sincerely doing the reviews? Thanks.

These are the answers I am referring to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29985985
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30013557

Comment: Can you explain why you think these two answers were sufficient? For the first one, they don't seem to have actually explained how their solution solves the problem. For the second one, the answer is "remove the curly braces" but there are no curly braces in the question code at all (that I can see, assuming curly braces are `{}`)...

Comment: I'll agree that the first one seems like a valid attempt to answer the question albeit without any useful explanation, but the second is a duplicate of [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983697) from 7 months previous.

Comment: @Catija I can confirm for you, yes, `{}` are indeed curly braces :)

Comment: @Catija But.. I think code only Answers are "Looks OK" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What I don't understand is how a Late Answer [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29784823) that concluded with "Looks OK" could generate an audit where the "correct" answer is not that.

Comment: @Catija Sometimes, [sometimes not](https://www.etsy.com/market/curly_braces). :-P

Comment: @IanCampbell I think the system is confused. It takes Answers that have been deleted for whatever reason and puts them in as audits. I can't see why it was deleted, but if it was 3 delete votes from subject matter experts, then using that as an audit is a problem.

Comment: @Scratte I'm not super fond of that rule but I'm also not going to use this as a place to dispute it. That said, I'm also not fond of the idea that the question isn't important when considering whether an answer is in fact an answer... and those two things in conjunction seem like they can lead to a lot of poor answers just sitting around downvoted.

Comment: @Catija That is how it works. Or how it's suppose to work. We vote and some of us delete them, unless they serve as a warning to not use the Answer.. it can prevent others from posting the same thing :)

Comment: @Scratte it was deleted in LQA - because we don't currently prevent stuff from appearing in multiple queues, so it was in First Answers, Late Answers and LQA all at the same time.  https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29898207

Comment: @Scratte The [first answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPkUv.png) was deleted at the conclusion of a [Low Quality Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU6ER.png) review task that completed with Recommend Deletion x1, Looks OK x 1, and Delete x3.

Comment: What I find bizarre about the second one (the one *without* curly braces) is that it has been used thrice as an audit and, in each case, the audit was failed with a "Looks OK" verdict. Scary.

Comment: @IanCampbell Interesting.. so that's a failure all around. Reviewers using the queue to delete answers instead of validating the "Not an Answer" rule, and hence making the system think that it was one.

Comment: The help center specifically says that answers should answer the question. At least one of those didn't.

Comment: Relevant: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: In case there's any confusion, [the regex answer works](https://regex101.com/r/YLALO8/1/)

Comment: @Catija - If poor answers sitting around downvoted is a problem, maybe it's time you guys gave the Roomba an upgrade.

Comment: @Scratte: For what it's worth, I've submitted [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412060/3025856) which I believe capturers our shared understanding here. I also used it as an opportunity to elevate the two links you referenced—which, IMHO, ought to be required reading for anyone flagging or reviewing answers. As an aside, when I was a fledgling reviewer contending with my own failed audits, you were instrumental in helping me understand the rubric and offering useful references to back it up, so it's hardly a surprise that I share your position (and confusion) here.

Comment: @Scratte It works with the given data, not with the given requirement. https://regex101.com/r/nU0dGb/1/

Comment: @Dharman Good spot. So.. it's half an Answer :)

Comment: @Scratte More like a comment actually. An answer would explain how to solve the problem. This is just some regex that was lucky to match the pattern. Not very useful information.

Comment: @Dharman Not sure that I agree with that. It does match the examples, just not a case with no spaces in the description. Answers that are not useful are downvoted on the site. Dangerous and "Not an Answers" are deleted. Btw, this seems to work `([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*)(?=;\w+$)` though I'm not sure that agl supports a lookaround.

Comment: @Scratte You are trying to fit a square block into a round hole. https://regex101.com/r/nU0dGb/2 It still doesn't work properly. The right solution should contain `[^;]` somewhere in the pattern.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do at all. I'm trying to say that if you think there's something wrong with the Answer you should vote on it. That's how we rate content, no? Not delete what we don't like. And `[^;]` will also match a line break.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Interesting enough, according to that FAQ, it doesn't suggest _recommending deletion_ for cases where "a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does". It does recommend that the reviewer "downvote; comment if practical". (Personally, I usually vote to delete in these cases, but I now realize that's inappropriate.)

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Scratte's comments, it is my understanding that sincere attempts to answer the question—even if they're wrong—should not be flagged as *Not an Answer*, nor recommended for deletion in *Low Quality Answers*. I would assume that criteria extends to *Late Answers* and *First Answers*.

#### Relevant Guidance

Per the [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/3025856) FAQ:

> Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!

> Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer.

Moderator @Undo's popular post, [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), extends this to the *Low Quality Answers* queue, where they note:

> For example, an answer might not have description for why the code works, but it still shouldn't be deleted; just leave a comment asking the author for an explanation, and move on.

> It may be *plain wrong*—but that's something for downvotes and comments to decide. Not deletion. This is why we have the voting system—if something is wrong, it should float to the bottom below all the other not-wrong things. This is the system working.

#### False Positives in Audits

Unfortunately, despite the above, there remains widespread confusion—if not outright *disagreement*—over these guidelines, and many reviewers will vote to delete any answer that is short, lacks an explanation (i.e., code-only answers), or appears to be wrong. (I like to assume this is out of ignorance, though some reviewers seem to do it as a willful protest to guidance they disagree with.) Regardless, as a result, you'll see these popup as audits. I've failed a few myself. It's not only frustrating, but inadvertently reproduces this habit by penalizing reviewers for making otherwise-correct votes.

#### Failed Audit #1: Code-Only Answer

Given this, I'd consider [your first audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29985985) a clear case of false positive. It isn't a terribly useful answer without an explanation, and it may not even be correct (see discussion between @Scratte and @Dharman [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412057/review-privileges-suspension-on-short-answers/412060?noredirect=1#comment871602_412057)), but it's offering a solution. I'd have left a comment requesting further explanation, but would also have voted "Looks OK".

#### Failed Audit #2: Duplicate Answers

One caveat to this is duplicate answers *[citation needed]*. Answers that repeat the same guidance as older answers are generally deleted, unless they add *significantly* more detail than the original answers. In the case of [your second audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30013557), that is clearly the case. As @Ian Campbell [correctly identified in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412057/review-privileges-suspension-on-short-answers/412060#comment871576_412057), it is a duplicate of [an older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602617/improper-token-passed/60983697#60983697), while offering dramatically less detail. Those can be trickier to spot, and especially for old questions with a lot of existing answers.

(*Confession:* I will often *Skip* questions with a lot of answers if I don't have time to compare answers to previous guidance.)

#### Conclusion

I haven't assessed the rest of your review history, and so I'm not in a position to comment on your suspension—I'll leave that to a moderator, who has the authority to do something about it. But, personally, I think your first failed audit was a false-positive, whereas the second one was valid, albeit very easy to miss.

Finally, I appreciate you taking the review process seriously, and checking in here to determine what the correct approach is.

Comment: If these review queues were the same, we wouldn't need separate queues.

Comment: Generally, I agree with your guidance, which is the right guidance for LQA. However, LA review demands that you not only check for NAA, but also whether the new answer is really needed on that question. Is it good enough to add any value whatsoever? Furthermore, the two reviews in LQA actually fall in the grey area. Deleting them in LQA was the right decision, but deciding "looks ok" wouldn't be a bad choice either.

Comment: @Dharman Except that last regex Answer is way more elegant than the convoluted ones already there. In my opinion the solution itself is better. And it doesn't even lead to backtracking. And this is why Subject Matter Experts should be doing the deleting of Answer that aren't "Not an answer"..

Comment: @Scratte As an SME I can confidently say that this regex does not solve the problem. It only accidentally solves the problem. The top answer is actually much better.

Comment: @Dharman: The queues _obviously_ serve different purposes. But the criteria for recommending deletion should be consistent across them. And that's especially true here since, apparently, the entire basis of the OP's failed audit was due to these answers being deleted in the _Low Quality Posts_ queue. If the decision of reviewers in _Low Quality Posts_ can trigger an audit in _First Answers_ or _Late Answers_, then I'd expect them to share criteria over what "Looks OK".

Comment: @JeremyCaney Correct, and they do share the same guidance. If it can be deleted in LQA then it should have been definitely deleted in LA. They were deleted in LQA, so the review in LA was definitely no right to say it looks ok.

Comment: @Dharman: Aside, I understand your point about _Late Answers_. And, honestly, it's something I struggle with. I end up skipping a _lot_ of answers because they look fine _per se_ (and may even look _good_), but are being added to questions with 10+ established answers, and I don't feel confident determining if they really add further value. In those cases, I try to leave a note asking how the answer improves upon the existing answers, and especially when some have been strongly validated by the community.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I understand. There is always the option to skip. If you have to add a comment asking for an explanation, chances are that it should have been just deleted instead.

Comment: I'd like to add that I do not agree with deleting an Answer that is wrong. That's not the guidance that I can see on meta at all. Not for the Low Quality Post and not for any other queue. Deleting posts for this reason carries a 20K reputation privilege and is to be done outside the queue.

Comment: @Scratte That's correct. Even 20k+ users should not delete wrong answers unless they are really harmful.

Comment: @Scratte: I've updated my answer to emphasize the bit about flagging or deleting _wrong_ answers, since that's a common point of confusion. Thank you for raising that point.

Comment: @JeremyCaney There is certainly a much better Answer on the regex post. And I am having a bit of a discussion about whether the Answer is wrong or how wrong it is. I appreciate your post here.

Comment: @Scratte: Thank you. I noticed that about your discussion with Dharman, and updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Not recommending deletion on a post that objectively should be deleted, just because you're in a queue, is absurd. The problem here is the audits, not the choices people are making in the queue.

Comment: @KevinB: What's your basis for "objectively should be deleted"? The real issue here seems to be a disagreement over the established guidelines (as cited above) of what should be deleted in the review queues. If you look at my answer, you'll see the level of quality I expect before posting to Stack Overflow; I'd love to delete answers that don't live up to my own standards. But, as a reviewer, it's my role to uphold the site's rules, not reinterpret them per my own preferences. As a trusted user, you obviously have more flexibility here, as you're trusted to make subjective quality assessments.

Comment: Answers that I, as someone with experience in that topic, can say beyond a shadow of a doubt are 100% incorrect. Not simply missing an explanation or are otherwise just low quality, but answers that are entirely wrong and have zero value.

Comment: @KevinB: That's a privilege afforded to you as a trusted user, and one I look forward to hopefully achieving myself some day. But, [as cited in my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), "It may be plain wrong—but that's something for downvotes and comments to decide. Not deletion." That's really explicit! If we believe that is incorrect guidance, we should open a debate on meta to challenge it, not just follow our own preference in the review queues.

Comment: That's simply altering the way the queues are processed to appease a broken audit system.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, my views are 100% aligned with the link you just cited.

Comment: What i'm saying is more along the lines of... Expecting users to act on a post differently than they normally would, just because they're in a queue where they may be hit with audits, is absurd. If a post is worthy of deletion it's worthy of deletion, whether your in a queue or not

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29985985:

- Compared to the other answers (which are available in the review window, just in another tab), the answer provided here doesn't justify why this regex is "useful".
- No indication that it actually solves or addresses the OP's problem at first glance.

Therefore, this would be a tough sell IMO to say that this answer is "OK".

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30013557:

- This is just a simple amount of text saying to remove some curly braces.
- Compared to the other answers, it doesn't even *seem like it's in context*.
- No indication that it actually solves or addresses OP's problem at first glance.

Therefore, this would be a *very* hard sell to say that this answer is "OK".

Comment: I don't get it. According to [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) attempts of answers are Answers too.

Comment: I'm confused for the same reasons as @scratte. If the first answer is a useful audit, I likely have _hundreds_ of bogus votes on _Low Quality Posts_, _Late Answers_, and now _First Answers_. My understanding has consistently been that _deleting_ is for answers that make no effort to address the question, not for answers that might be incorrect, or are comparatively less useful than existing answers—unless, of course, they're repeats. (The second answer repeats guidance from [a _much_ more comprehensive previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983697/3025856), so I would have flagged it.)

Comment: [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) > whatever throughts someone said on meta.

Comment: @JeremyCaney if you ignore meta and start reading the help center, you will wonder why the heck meta contradicts it. Somehow a mess about "wrong" answers got mixed in with "non-answers".

Comment: Does this queue delete those answers?  I dunno, I haven't been in those queues in nigh on six years.  To be perfectly honest though, I put myself out here as an attempt to start an answer about this as opposed to facilitating a discussion in comments, since...well, comments aren't answers, and someone's gotta start *answering* these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Braiam: That article is about how to write _good_ answers. Nobody here is suggesting that these are _good_ answers. The question is whether _not-good_ answers should be _deleted_.

Comment: @Makoto: If I understand the process right, neither _Late Answers_ or _First Answers_ will _delete_ the answers, but _Recommend Deletion_ will send it to _Low Quality Posts_, where four "Recommend Deletion" votes _will_ delete it. And, indeed, that's what happened in this case; the audit was failed _because_ reviewers in _Low Quality Posts_ voted to delete it, which invalidated the OP's "Looks OK" vote.

Comment: @JeremyCaney It's basically the specific guidance part of the ["well if you didn't follow that this is what happens"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), note the opening statement and the last point on that unordered list.

Comment: @Braiam: That link reinforces the _exact_ point that I am making. It notes that "answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed", and provides the familiar list of reasons why. As for the last bullet, nothing about a _partial answer_ implies that it must be a _correct_ answer. These answers _do_ attempt to answer the question.

Comment: To flag or not to flag is a different discussion than recommend deletion vs looks ok.

Comment: @KevinB Not really. Deleting in the queue makes anyone not able to actually put delete votes on a post in a position to delete a post. The queue isn't suppose to work like that. It's just to validate the flag.

Comment: The queue is there to assist in the cleanup of the site by putting posts that potentially need cleanup in front of people looking to do so.

Answer (score -1):

These two answers don't really address the questions they were posted to. For this reason, the correct action to take in the Late Answers review queue would be "delete". Why? The explanation of this review queue says:

> - **Delete** answers that do not address the question at all, are link-only, or are incomprehensible.

These answers don't look ok and your action was incorrect.

- The [regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29985985) doesn't explain how this regex helps with matching delimiters. [It solves the problem](https://regex101.com/r/ZXVJeu/1/) but in a very hacky way. Given there is no real explanation, one might consider it a coincidence that this particular regex "is useful".
- The [Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30013557) says to remove braces. What braces? How does that solve the problem? Why are the braces a problem at all? How is it a one-line solution? There isn't even one line of code in that answer. Is it an answer? Maybe, but is it a good answer? Certainly not.

There is a second small problem here. These answers were deleted in LQA review. And this review has the same guidance as the LA review queue. However, it is advisable not to delete answers that look like answers here. LQA handles mostly posts that are not an answer at all. Answers that are low quality are often deleted through this review, as this is one of our main tools to combat low-quality answers, but if they look like they could be answers they might slip through. I have voted "looks ok" for one of them without realizing the answer is really low quality.

Reviewers of LQA look primarily for NAAs. Posts are added here both through user-raised flags and system-raised flags. They can be from a brand new question or a very old question. It would be really helpful if the first delete vote came from LA review.

Reviewers of LA look for added value. Does the new answer add any value to the existing answers? Was it warranted to post that answer? Can it be edited to add a simple explanation or is unclear what the author wanted to teach? The job of the reviewer is to evaluate the perceived usefulness of the post without judging its correctness.

Don't worry. We all make mistakes and it's easy to make mistakes in reviews. My advice is to take your time. Review suspensions are meant to raise your awareness and it looks like it did a good job in your case. By asking on Meta you will receive a lot of useful feedback. Once you understand why your reviews were wrong, a moderator might consider lowering the suspension.