# Why does reviewing in the late answer queue require knowledge in specific topics?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension, late-answers

Recently I was suspended for failing the following Late Answers audits.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29691097) 
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30145867)

While the second answer was reviewed incorrectly, the first answer did look like an attempt to answer the vague question.

Here is the question:

> I have create kylin cube and when it query it does not showing any data.
> I am totally new to Data warehouse and Apache Kylin.
> What needs to be done next?

Here was the answer which I see as an attempt to answer the above question:

> After creating the cube, you need to build the cube. After the build job is completed, you can query it. You can view this document: https://kylin.apache.org/docs/gettingstarted/kylin-quickstart.html

It doesn't seem like a link only answer to me (the correctness of the answer need not be assessed when reviewing).

But looks like other reviewers deleted it, calling it a link only answer.

After the suspension, I re-read the late answer help centre (emphasis mine):

> While many late answers are merely saying “Thanks!” or are attempts to ask follow-up questions and should be deleted, **in other cases it may require specific knowledge of the topic**. If you’re unsure whether the answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip” option.

As I have read, I am not required to look into the correctness of the answer, but the above sentence makes it seem like you might need to do so.

Can't it just be downvoted, like reviewing other questions (ie when you have knowledge in that field)? Is "recommend deletion" necessary? Also, was I rightfully suspended? If so, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: I am now not entirely sure why this question has so many downvotes, I don't see this as a bad question, neither have I found this question on this site. Is it because it's already downvoted that people tend to downvote even more?

Comment: @art 7 downvotes is actually not a lot for meta standards. Voting here is different, people don't vote on the usefulness of a question but more on a personal level. It's best not to try and read anything in votes placed and instead look at the response you get - two answers and not a mountain of comments telling you how you are wrong is pretty good :) Good on you for asking the question, keep it up (after searching first, of course).

Comment: @Gimby oh thx for the clarification. I thought that the voting was based on the usefulness of the question.

Comment: @Art on the main Q&A site, definitely yes! But if meta would be the same... we wouldn't be able to discuss and share opinions. The fact that meta runs on the same software which is designed towards voting based on quality makes it a little... quirky.

Comment: @gnat No it is an entirely different question. I am not just asking why was the correct answer was marked wrong, but also why is it that only a late answer has requires knowledge in a specific field

Comment: Recommending deletion is not necessary. Downvoting or commenting would have passed the audit (which is why I mention that part of the guide in my answer).

Comment: @yivi The edit was to stop people from voting as duplicate.

Comment: accepted answer there, as well as its [duplicate FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/839601) cover this and in particular explain where your understanding is wrong. In brief - no, you don't really need subject matter experience when late answer is flag-worthy or is poorly formatted, poorly worded, etc etc - ie in cases when you need to pick review actions to improve it. It is only when you are going to submit review that answer is good as is, topic knowledge becomes highly desirable, and besides you need to do some additional research (check that it's not plagiarised, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In "Late Answers" your actions are less constrained than in other queues like "Low Quality Answers". You are not simply judging "this merits deletion or not". You are also reviewing for quality, and that many times requires subject matter expertise.

> "As I have read, I am not required to look into the correctness of the answer".

That's true for "Low Quality Answers". For "Late Answers" or "First Answers", reviewers need to be able to finesse a bit more (and to skip more often, otherwise)

About the "correctness" of the suspension... review suspensions serve two purposes: to stop users from continue reviewing incorrectly, and to educate them so they can better review in the future.

I'm just a humble monkey, not a mighty moderator, but if you show that you understand why you failed the audits, so that it's clear that you are  likely to be a better reviewer in the future, the lifting of a suspension by a diamond moderator is not unheard of.

In this case, the review-audit you admit you handled incorrectly is *the more recent one*, which would make the case for suspension stronger.

In the meantime, you can always use the time to re-read material like [this excellent guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-the-late-answers-and-first-questions-answers) on how to better use the Late Answers, First Answers and First Questions queues. By following that guide (it's much easier than it looks), one is almost guaranteed never to be caught flat-footed by a review-audit.

For example, applying the advice of this guide to your failed audit from August, any of these two bullet-points would have helped:

> - Is something you have no idea:
>
>   - Skip this sucker!

Or:

> - Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough, especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new:
>
>   - Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does; if so:
>
>     - Downvote; comment if practical.

Either strategy would have helped you avoiding failing the audit.

Comment: looks like the late answer queue doesn't fit my knowledge base. Also, isn't downvoting good enough for incorrect answers? should it still be flagged?

Comment: Voting is enough. Flagging is not used for "incorrect" answers. There is no flag for "technically wrong, incomplete or inaccurate". But we do have votes and comments for those.

Comment: sorry I meant "recommend deletion".

Comment: "Recommend deletion" is basically "flagging". If I encountered this audit, I'd probably wouldn't recommend deletion. But if I saw a similarly poor answer on a subject matter I considered myself knowledgeable, I would almost certainly vote and/or comment.

Comment: FYI, in Late Answers you can filter the tasks by tag. https://cln.sh/d6l7ST This way, you'd be taking care in tasks where you'd feel more comfortable judging the quality, and would make the most difference.

Comment: Ok, thx didn't notice that.

Answer (score -1):

The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29691097) is a bad audit, brought on by [incorrect reviewing in the Low Quality Answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29549245).  One incorrectly said it was link-only.  Two of the reviewers correctly voted that this answer Looks OK, one even pointing out in the comments that it's not link-only.  The low quality answers queue is [not, despite the name, supposed to be deleting answers that are *merely* low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/208273).  This appears to contain an answer to the question: the reason the asker's queries are not showing any data is because they need to build the cube first*.  I've flagged this incorrect review for moderator attention.

---

As you correctly note, though, the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30145867) is another story.  This is barely comprehensible (I figured it out only after looking at the other answer to the question):

> anybody looking for soln in the future can use the command line to solve this issue, IDLE is not printing "print statements from processes

This doesn't require domain knowledge to realize that this is unclear.  It should at least receive a downvote or a comment explaining this, but an edit to improve it if you can work out what it says would be even better (and this is where domain knowledge could help).

---

* I should note that I don't have any domain knowledge here, so I have no idea whether this answer is actually *correct*.  But it *is* an answer.

Comment: I don't agree the first one is a "bad audit". That it was deleted by other users (even if deleted for the "wrong reasons") mostly signals it's a post with quality issues, and that simply choosing "Looks OK" is not the right thing to do. That was actually true in this case: the post did have quality issues, and selecting "Looks OK" was not "OK" or the right choice for this queue. The problem is treating LA with the same binary approach than LQA. It's not simply "delete or not delete" choice.

Comment: @yivi In my opinion, it's a mediocre answer.  It's not _great_, but it's not so bad that it clearly needs corrective action.  The answer stands on its own without the link, and makes a bona fide attempt at suggesting a solution to the problem.  It then suggests a document where someone could read more about the process.  Would it be better if they'd included more of that (especially the parts about building the cube)?  Yes.  Is it a bad answer in clear need of negative feedback?  I don't think so.  It's certainly not clear enough for an audit.

Comment: If that kind of answer was posted on a tag I knew enough about, I'd vote or comment. It's utterly incomplete and the link is 95% irrelevant. I don't think the answer "does not need negative feedback", particularly if one finds it in the LA queue.